# What should we do with our favourite UserVoice requests?

Tags: discussion, uservoice

Clearly [UserVoice](https://web.archive.org/web/20090303193027/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/filter/recent?days=14) is still present, and has a lot of content. There are requests there that I'm really keen on, and I'd like them to be discussed further on Meta. (I strongly suspect that UserVoice discussion will fizzle very quickly.)

Is it reasonable to repost requests here (after checking for duplication, of course) with a link to the original UserVoice request, making changes to the proposal to take account of the existing comments?

My main concern is that this will cause a flurry of activity, making it impossible to keep up with Meta for a few days - and in particular, a lot of ideas which would get significant discussion in "slower times" will get very little attention in the stampede. This could be avoided by a semi-automated trickle migration from UV, but I also like the idea that if people really care about ideas, those are the ones which should be migrated first. (That's not necessarily the same as those with the highest votes, necessarily.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with John Smithers -- pick your favorites and copy n' paste them over here.

I apologize, but in all honesty, there are far too many requests for us to ever get through on UserVoice. I've spent marathon sessions of hours trying to go through them all (not just the top 50) and it's just .. impossible.

Also, some of them date from almost a year ago and I am unsure how relevant they still are in our current brave new world of site status.

So if someone would like to play "editorial review" and pick the "best" UserVoice requests and plop them over here, that'd be fantastic!

Comment: How is this going to be any different? Soon enough this'll be inundated with requests. What's more they'll be mixed in with just requests for information and chit-chat. You can't really sort by vote unless you delete the closed issues. Is that the plan?

Comment: @cletus: At last Jeff realized, that uservoice is no good replacement for a bug tracking system. But as I said: take not more than one. Then this kind of "overflow" should be manageable.

Comment: the tagging will be crucially important, along with moderator-only tags (just to prevent non-mods from "accidentally" interfering).

Comment: No need to apologise, IMO. You can't implement everything, and I don't think anyone really expects you to. I'll take the "one at a time" approach, dropping my votes from the UV items as I do so to keep track of what I've done :)

Answer (score 8):

Keep it simple, keep it small. Pick the one request you wanted the most to be implemented in SO and post it. If it's done take the next.

Answer (score 5):

**Don't do anything**.

Just wait for people to copy/paste their pet request. It may be rude, but Ron Jeffries wrote a nice article summing it up called [Petition the King](http://ronjeffries.com/xprog/articles/petitiontheking/)

Comment: **`+1`** for the link.

Comment: @Brad: It seems a little rude, but has served me many times actually :-)