# Should the weight of downvotes be increased?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, reputation, down-votes

When we started Stack Overflow, we wanted to make sure that downvotes were more of a visual and psychological motivator than a punitive action. That's why

- upvotes are +10
- downvotes are -2, and cost the casting voter -1

However, recently, I've seen Marc Gravell and Jon Skeet both say similar things:

> IMO, downvotes don't quite carry enough... -5 downvotes and +1 upvote (for sympathy) yields zero points overall; or it could even yield +10 points for a new user! I'd prefer to see, say, -4 points? -5 points?

I am starting to come around to this way of thinking. There are some users who ask a lot of questions that get downvoted *heavily*, but over time these users end up with a fairly sizable amount of reputation.

This doesn't feel right.

**We are considering changing downvotes to -5, with the same -1 cost to the casting voter.**

There really aren't that many downvotes in the system, so the net effect of this change would be to reduce rep growth for users who tend to get downvoted as much as they get upvoted. (Yes, I realize this is no panacea: over time, we'll still get rep inflation for marginal users based on sheer quantity; this is only one of several changes we are considering to help mitigate this.)

The other downside to this change, besides the obvious minor loss of rep for most users, is that it would force **a global reputation recalc for every user**. I think we're due for one of those anyway.

Comment: I like this, but I would raise the weight for users with reputation > X.

Comment: I have to ask - are these 'marginal' users causing problems? How? I just want to make sure there isn't some sort of 'anti-noob' bias here.

Comment: @jinuy - I'm not sure that is workable; that just makes tactical / revenge voting more accented towards high rep users...

Comment: Even though I'm supportive of the -5/-2 initiative. The -2 for downvotes would put me back beneath 3k. =(. Can I appeal for an exception =P

Comment: (as an aside - if you have the bonnet up for a recalc, you might want to exclude the self-voting that sometimes results from account merges...)

Comment: Jeff - as it's a major change it would be worth making an announcement on all the sites just before it happens to explain and hopefully prevent a lot of "I just lost X rep - WTF" messages.

Comment: It would not "force" a global recalc.  It would work fine without a recalc.  The recalc will attract far more complaints than any extra penalty for bad questions/answers.

Comment: @Marc, you mean there are some people who down-vote their own stuff?

Comment: There should definitely be a notice on all of the sites. It would give people a chance to delete all of their questions/answers that currently have more down-votes than up-votes.

Comment: @finnw - recalcs happen occasionally; better to deal with it all in one go.

Comment: I say this only somewhat facetiously, but global recalc is unconstitutional. You can't change the law, then punish people for something they did that was legal at the time but now illegal. It's perfectly possible to write a database query that will use one calculation scheme before the cutoff date and a different one after. I support the +5/-2 proposal, but I don't support a global recalc (and my rep is only like 350, so I don't have anything to lose personally--just don't think it's right).

Comment: Rather than the -2 to -5 change, I'd like to see it just not award rep points for upvotes to questions or answers with a negative score.  Much the same effect, but less disruptive to users who play by the rules.

Comment: I've seen answers that were at -1, but were actually correct (mainly on tricky questions). I upvoted them and eventually they properly reached the top, but should their first upvote not count?

Comment: Joel that would get rather sticky when dealing with questions hovering around the 0 +1 -1 upvotes stage. The user's rep would swing wildly if he had 4 upvotes, and three downvotes, then he gets two downvotes, and loses all 40 positive point.

Comment: @devinb: That's not at all what I'm proposing. I'm only talking about the state of the question at the time the vote is cast.  You could potentially 'lose' a lot of rep if you have a question that goes back and forth several times between -1 and 0, but that's a different thing.

Comment: @devinb: I wrote this up a while back, perhaps my long-winded proposal will help to clarify... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/should-we-reduce-rep-bonus-for-upvotes-on-posts-with-a-negative-score

Comment: @DanThMan I'm afraid I disagree - your rep is not something you own. It only really has value relative to what everyone else's got.  Everyone's rep would be recalculated, and the relative ranking afterwards would better reflect their actual kudos on the site.

Comment: Doesn't the EULA state that the rep points remain property of stackoverflow?

Comment: Can we expect to see this happening soon?

Comment: -1 it feels like changing the rules of the game midstream

Comment: It isn't a game.  **It is a question and answer site.**

Comment: Any news on when this will be happening?

Comment: The only problem is if someone doesn't have that great of a post and then all 20 people that view it each down vote it because it wasn't very good, even though it didn't deserve that.

Comment: Downvoters should be forced to write a comment telling why is the downvote. This would help with this "tactic downvote" thing.

Comment: @Jeff: Please don't go with -5/-2.  Or at least make the change to -5 first, and only increase the voter penalty to -2 if there is evidence of a problem with leaving it at -1.  If you make the changes one at a time you'll be able to measure the impacts independently.

Comment: if the cost of a downvote is changed, we should have the ability to change our downvotes.

Comment: @antony: why? you meant them didn't you?

Comment: Soon? *Please* tell me this will be soon.

Comment: Create a table for the downvote value and a daterange. (Begin-date, End-date, post-value, voter-value). Voila, no global recalc

Comment: Downvotes should force a comment if the penalty is to go up.

Comment: Is this still planned?

Comment: After the recalc, everyone who downvoted should be required to add a comment to every downvote before they are able to answer anymore questions.

Comment: @Roboto: that is ridiculous. I have given 357 downvotes, and I'm sure there are users with way more than that. Forcing people to leave comments for each one would result in thousands of comments that read "asdfasdfasdf" or something equally meaningless.

Comment: @Graeme: It's just as ridiculous as recalc'ing the downvote a year later.. as someone already pointed out, don't penalize someone because the law has already changed. It's not too hard to determine if you left a comment on a downvote. It would make you think next time you downvote and don't leave a comment! :)

Comment: I support the idea of forcing comments for down-votes, but I would also suggest that up-voting an existing comment on that answer would be enough. Anonymous criticism makes no sense, which is exactly what todays down-votes are. *(There are few things more annoying than getting down-voted without a reason why.)* - I would not support making this retroactive, however. It would force many active members to spend a lot of time to regain their posting privileges, which would probably drive a lot of them away.

Comment: There is not proportion between a −5 for who gets a down-vote, and −1 for who down-votes. Considering that it takes more time to give an answer than to click on a button, I think there would be more appreciation for who tries to answer that for who (maybe without reading the full question) thinks the answer is not useful. I think there should be a limit in the number of down-votes made from users with a lower reputation.

Comment: My forced downvote comment would default to "Take that. Hah!" for 15 character. As much as I dislike drive-by downvotes, forcing a comment is simply an invitation to uniformative or unhelpful comments

Comment: @dmckee, Even so, it would identify the one who down-voted and give you a reason for it. Your `"Take that. Hah!"` comment would simply tell me that some idiot *(no offence)* down-voted me for no good reason. - If you can't explain *why* you are down-voting, you probably shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: @Atli Your answer is wrong and incomplete. Someone posted a complete, correct answer that's been massively upvoted. You could probably take a hint from the correct answer as to what's wrong with yours, I don't have to say: "his answer is better, look over it". Not everything has to be explained.

Comment: @"I hate haikus". Good point. Perhaps requiring a comment is overdoing it, but in my opinion, requiring to many comments is better than allowing to few. Helps keep people honest. - Perhaps, instead, it would be better to just automatically identify the down-voters. That would at least help identify those who just down-vote everybody else to promote themselves.

Comment: This is fine, as long as it is calculated from the change going forward.  It is unfair to change the rules retroactively.

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks...

Comment: Why just not to make upvotes = +2 instead of +10?

Comment: @dmckee, if your downvote comment read "Take that!", I'd simply flag it for moderator attention. I'm all for requiring a comment or an upvote on an existing downvote comment when downvoting.

Comment: @avakar: and what? Expect the moderators to review masses of votes? The point is that the forced comment could just as well be the purest disingenuous blather, and you'll never know...

Comment: @jia33p: Because All the other scales on the site would then need to be re-engineered, too. Take a heck of a long time to get to 10k going 2 at a time..

Comment: @dmckee: what do you mean "masses"? There won't be any masses if you remove repeated offenders from circulation.

Comment: Is there some worry this will generate unwanted behavior somehow and that's why it's being postponed?

Comment: @Downvoter: Its just taking 6-8 weeks.

Comment: You need to take in to account people who revenge downvote whenever someone posts a comment pointing out an error in their answer.  It is easy to go to someone's user profile and downvote multiple answers if you are pissed about their comment.  Some people are really childish.

Comment: @aaronis: There is an automated process that seeks out suspicious voting patterns and cancels them out. If you think that you've been the victim of tactical downvoting, bring it to the attention of the moderators.

Comment: Somebody doesn't know how to comment. **Re:Version#3**

Comment: When will this come into effect?

Comment: @George - 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Will this result in a recount at that time? I'm not too concerned... I might lose 20-30 points, but not too much.

Comment: @George - As per the last line of the post, *"The other downside to this change, besides the obvious minor loss of rep for most users, is that it would force a global reputation recalc for every user."* - also, the 6 to 8 weeks thing is a joke/meme, and there's currently no published timeline.

Comment: Declined?! Darn, I was genuinely looking forward to this change

Comment: Me too! Too bad.

Comment: "recently, I've seen Marc Gravell and Jon Skeet both say similar things"  <--Comedy!!  What does either of these two know about downvoting?

Comment: How can this be declined, while there's so much support for it, while something much more controversial (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting) is implemented? (Look at the votes.)

Comment: @fretje Seriously? Jeff rules with an iron first.  Sure he says this place is run by the users but we all know that really BS and this proves it.

Comment: I think this is a horrible idea.

Comment: 47 comments....

Comment: I think there SHOULD be a recalculation for all users.

Comment: @DanM: We're not punishing them, we're merely removing further privileges.

Comment: @Keith - the rep, unfortunately, does have meaning other than relative to others. It enables some very useful features, such as seeing total up & down votes, or editing anyone's answer for grammar.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Having had a few months to think about this, I'm no longer sure it's a good idea, for two reasons.

1. Downvotes were always essentially cosmetic, with an extremely minor effect on reputation. Despite this, received downvotes are taken quite seriously by users. Almost too seriously. If we raise them to -5 they are no longer cosmetic but can be wielded as cudgels on other users. This was never the intent of a downvote, so we would be twisting it into something ugly. Users are far, far more attached to their reputation scores than I ever could have predicted, and I believe more than doubling the weight of a downvote will cause a *lot* of new, additional angst in the community over the occasional received downvote -- to the point that only users who want to hurt other users will cast them. **Downvotes go from being cosmetic and psychological to weapons of war.**
2. If we amplify the effect of a downvote, in all fairness, we must also amplify the cost to the casting voter as well. So what was -2 to the post, with -1 to the casting voter, will become -5/-2 or even -5/-3. The only reason we had downvotes cost -1 was to make people really think about using downvotes in moderation, only when appropriate. For such an extremely minor cost, users with 20k+ rep are still hesitant to cast downvotes for fear of losing reputation! Our goal is *not* to prevent people from casting downvotes, and it seems that given the current observed behavior (that is, very few people cast downvotes -- though a tiny select few cast a lot) **we would be causing the majority of users to cast *even fewer* downvotes than they do now**. This is, in my mind, a HUGE downside to this proposed change. We would be effectively nerfing downvotes into oblivion because they're now twice as "expensive" to cast.

The real problem I want to solve here is ["shore, there is always gold"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold). I am no longer convinced this is the right way to do it, but I am open to hearing ideas on that thread on other ways we could do it.

Comment: +1 I agree with this decision *at this time*. Each Trilogy site is as much a social experiment as it is a focused Q&A website. It's really difficult to make such a sudden fundamental change for such a big group of people. I think if we can come up with a way to test a modified reputation system with a set of voluntary users, that would allow us to make a better decision. All we have right now is forethought and hypotheticals.

Comment: It's sad that high rep users won't downvote becuase of the loss of reputation. I'm only on 8k on SF, but I relish the oppertunity to downvote, and the cost of -1 is negligable.

Comment: *Downvotes go from being cosmetic and psychological to weapons of war.* May be some people should stop worrying so much about reputation?

Comment: @voyager we have created a monster -- but a monster for GOOD! right? right???

Comment: @Farseeker: See http://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders. 819 downvotes.

Comment: @John if only others were more liberal with their rep :)

Comment: Not even -5/-2 for questions?

Comment: @perbert Most of us has a goal here, and this goal directly or indirectly rep-dependent. If this goal is fulfilled, the activity typically hugely decreases. Thus, the rep is extremely important for the active users.

Answer (score 292):

**Yes**, definitely -5 for a down-vote for the down-votee, but then I would also "up" the cost to -2 for the down-voter.
The higher cost will reduce the "just feels like it" down-vote behaviour some people are displaying.

Comment: I agree with this.

Comment: And this might also reduce the number of people who down-vote all answers that aren't their own

Comment: Yes, -5/-2 sounds like a reasonable trade-off.

Comment: I reckon a downvote should take half the value of an upvote, and cost half that again. Given you need a global recalc to do this effectively, I like the idea of it being powers of two, so +8 for an upvote, and -4 (at a -2 cost) for a downvote. You could even throw in a +1 for every ten times a comment gets up voted :)

Comment: The **only reason** to up the penalty to -2 is, if there is a problem that too many people are downvoting stuff, the stats do not seem to back that up.

Comment: There are some people *( you know who )*, who have more down-votes than up-votes, who would lose a lot of reputation if the cost of casting down-votes increased.

Comment: @Brad: Don't thinks that's so bad. As I see it, that behaviour (having more down-votes than upvotes) is generally 'frowned upon' by the community.

Comment: If you notice, I didn't specify whether this was a good thing, or a bad thing. I just left a thought provoking comment.

Comment: Ow, sorry then, I thought you said that like it was a bad thing... my appologies for the misunderstanding ;-)

Comment: Important: have a look at the impact of this change in my post below. -2 will heavily punish serial downvoters (RichB will lose almost half his rep). Problem users do not seem to downvote much. Further more, problem users get a lot less sympathy votes than people think.

Comment: There are a lot of knee-jerk downvotes. I've gotten a few for perfectly valid responses, where people were agreeing with me in the comments, but others were downvoting without giving any explanations.

Comment: I disagree.  Changing to -5 is a step in the right direction (I favour -10 to make up votes and down votes equivalent).  However, I am strongly against changing the penalty for the voter to -2.  In fact I'm strongly against any penalty for down-voting.  People should not be penalised for casting a deserved down-vote.  I understand why it was introduced, but I think there are better solutions to that problem.

Comment: @DanDyer maybe there should be some system for charging -2 for a downvote, then "refunding" those votes if the answer/question receives a downvote from others.

Comment: maybe the -2-1 cost for downvoting is void if you supply a comment?

Comment: @Kevin I actually like that idea considering how frustrating it can be to get downvoted with no reason why. "Explain yourself or pay up" is a good motto for downvoting.

Comment: @Kevin & statenjason that will lead to the comment: I don't want to lose any rep.

Comment: @lagerdalek. True, but you'd see who was doing the downvotes.

Comment: +100 for requiring a downvote comment.  Real annoying to get down-voted on (what you thought was) a legitimate answer with no explanation.  De-anonymizing it would help.

Comment: I agree that the down-vote should be more substantial to the person asking the question...-5 sounds good. Increasing the cost to down-vote is also a good idea. But lets face it, -5/-2 are huge costs to someone like myself with <200 rep on meta, <500 rep on SO. For those with rep >1k, that's not really much at all. I think (just my gut instinct) your largest group of *offenders* will come from the 1k - 2.5k rep range. Just a guess...

Comment: @bmoeskau: you can't *de-anonymize* the down-votes. I couldn't agree more that it is simply meaningless to down-vote a question or answer without something explaining why. A 3-point cost to down-vote, with +1 rep refunded upon comment would be acceptable to me.

Comment: @Gary: Not if I comment "Excellent post you have there, looks like you spent some time on it. Wish I could help!" after I downvote it ;-)

Comment: Oh wow, 10 people down voted this ... I should down vote it too! Sorry, but mob mentality comes into play. Just forcing a comment for a down vote would suffice. If you can't articulate a reason for a down vote, well, why are you down voting? SO is very good at catching retribution in votes, what is the issue in enforcing mandatory comments?

Comment: And then there's also the "Hey, down vote this and up vote mine" from the people-who-really-need-to-leave-moms-basement department.

Comment: @waffles, Wait, why had this been rejected?

Comment: @Pacerier waffles is retired

Comment: @waffles, Still, all seems to be in favor. I don't understand why this is turned down. What's the reason?

Answer (score 81):

I think -1 cost for -5 downvote is too low. It should be -2 or if it stays -1 it should be -3 or -4 (maybe).

Additionally, I think points lost by downvoting should be returned if the post or answer in question is deleted.

If the argument for downvoting costing rep is to improve the quality of questions and answers on the site then perhaps we should incentivize people to delete downvoted content (of theirs) by returning any rep lost to them. I think this will happen with a rep recalc anyway but those are infrequent.

Lastly, if the "downvotee" edits the question so you can change your vote, if this happens on a different day I don't think the daily rep calc properly works with this. This should be corrected.

Comment: "I think points lost by downvoting should be returned if the post or answer in question is deleted." -- this is always true, it just requires a rep recalc

Comment: +1 for the rep points get returned

Comment: @Jeff, that's pretty much irrelevant.  Your rep will get recalculated maybe 2 or 3 times in a lifetime.

Comment: @finnw: there's no guarantee of that. I for one would prefer to see them happen more often...

Comment: "how often" moved here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/how-often-is-reputation-recalculated

Comment: +1 for the rep points get returned

Comment: I agree. If I see that you downvoted my answer, I should be able to delete it and get my points back because I realize that it was a bad answer.

Comment: There's a problem in that. If the question has one upvoted answer you can't delete it anymore. If you can't delete it, you can't get your rep points back. And there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Further from your 'Lastly...', if the downvotee edits his/her answer, there should be an incentive for the downvoter to change his/her mind and rescind the downvote.

Comment: Yeah I was really annoyed at myself for asking a really stupid question (maybe my 2nd/3rd night on SO)...I got downvoted badly...I deleted the question. But my rep didn't get refunded. At first I thought, "well, that's crappy, I learned my lesson." However, I really see the value in not getting the rep refunded - boy did I *really* learn my lesson!!!

Answer (score 70):

As you are increasing the penalty of a down-vote I think you ought to strengthen the "nudge" that prompts people to explain the down-vote.

For example, perhaps in this case the cost to the down-voter should be increased to -2 unless they provide a (possibly anonymous) comment, in which case it's -1 or even 0.

**EDIT** As Jon Skeet suggested in his comment a way to avoid the "afsdrwi" type comment would only to refund the rep if a certain number (2, 5?) of people voted the comment as useful.

I know you've implemented the "have you considered an explanation" to the down-vote button for lower rep users, but with the greater cost you might need a greater nudge.

Comment: I like the idea that A down vote costs a bit more if you don't enter a reason.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes

Comment: My only problem is...you can't force a useful comment. If all it takes is me typing in "gigglefarts" as a comment to lessen the penalty for my downvote, I'm going to do it every single time :)

Comment: I agree with TheTXI here.  I'd *love* to see people leave good reasons for every downvote cast, but I don't see a way to enforce it.  I think you'll see a lot of "asdfqwerty" comments if you do.

Comment: @Bill, I disagree. I think you'll find more "asdfasdfasdfasdf" comments. Why leave the home keys?

Comment: @TheTXI,Bill/devinb: Hence my suggestion a while ago that it would only refund once someone else had upvoted the comment. There are still various counterarguments, certainly - not least complexity - but it's at least an attempt to work around the "useless comment" syndrome.

Comment: @Jon: That's a good recommendation. I'd never read it before now.

Comment: And if that keeps up, we'll need to be able to downvote comments, as well.

Comment: Being required to leave a comment to no lose that one extra rep point, mean that your down-vote is no longer anonymous.

Comment: It would be anonymous to the end user, but obviously not to the system. Anyway, it was just a suggested mechanism.

Comment: I like the idea of encouraging comments for downvotes with reduced penalties, but I dont see why a comment on a downvote should be anonymous.  If you are commenting you should be credited.  If you are commenting with 'asdf' just to avoid getting dinged, you can be flagged as spam.

Comment: @akf - the fear is that if the down-vote is effectively credited then the recipient will retaliate. Though this might be less of a problem with the increased cost.

Comment: @ChrisF: I see that, but couldnt that be tracked with appropriate stats on the SO db?  It should be easy enough to flag those that have been downvoted as retaliating against their downvoters with timestamps, etc.  @Kelly French, you're on my list ;)

Comment: @jjnguy RT is retweet - it should be RC - recomment.

Comment: if someone posts a comment like asdsadfa for downvoting, and another reader happens to come across that comment, that comment should be able to be downvoted, and the commenter should lose 20 reps.

Comment: Even if it didn't show who posted the comment, the fact that they happened at the same time, would mean that they aren't really that anonymous.

Comment: The comment itself is less important than removing anonymity for downvoting.  IMO if you don't want to put your name on it, you should not be doing it.  Too many people downvote because of opinion or personal preference, not because the answer is actually inappropriate or not useful.  Removing the "troll" factor would help.

Answer (score 65):

I don't know - this really feels wrong some how.  Even at -2 we already have a lot of people complaining about getting downvoted.  -5 would make that much worse.

A subtler change that would have almost the same effect is just **don't award rep points for upvotes to questions or answers with a negative score at the time of the vote.**  If the complaint is that some users are slowly accumulating a lot of rep as a result of "pity voting", than just target the pity votes rather than all votes.

Unfortunately, it seems like the new -5/-2 change is already decided :(

---

As an aside, I was opposed to changing this at all in the past because it looked like a solution in search of a problem. So a few users gain a little extra rep score.  So what?

If they're using SO that much they've still invested something of themselves in the site and therefore still earned a certain amount of trust.  Beyond that point is doesn't matter; rep is just a toy.  Trying to make rep meaningful beyond that is ultimately futile.  Who cares if they're gaming the system?  Providing good answers is still a much faster way to earn rep, and so they're never going to pass any of the big contributors.

There might be some concern these users don't really understand the system, and so will abuse the abilities they gain from higher rep.  But if they don't even care enough to post thoughtful content to their own questions, they're unlikely to use these powers much if at all.

I've recently realized this view was *wrong.*  On one hand, I'm saying these users have "invested something of themselves in the site."  On the other, I acknowledge they "don't even care enough to post thoughtful content to their own questions."  So which is it?  Well, both.  They *do* care.  But their actions demonstrate that they don't care as much as I thought, or care about things that don't align with the site's values.  Therefore they have not really demonstrated that they've earned any trust, and something should be done to correct this.  Whether or not they would actually abuse the trust or use it all, even correctly, isn't really relevant until they actually earn it.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not that "people complain about getting down-voted" but that "people down-vote too easily"?

Comment: Eh- that's not my main point.  Changing it to -5 now just feels too much like changing the rules halfway through the game.  What I really want to see is the suggestion from my 2nd paragraph implemented instead.

Comment: I think this is a fantastic idea...

Comment: why can't we do both of these things?

Comment: I suppose you could, but is one really necessary if you also do the other?  And of the two, I think this is really the better fix.

Comment: I don't see changing the downvote to -5 as "changing the rules" more than some of the other stuff that gets implemented (e.g. the tracking of abuse is also implemented at a later time). Again... I don't see the "pity voting" the problem here, but rather the "down-voting to below 0".

Comment: @fretje: everything *starts out* at 0 - if it's bad, then a down-vote will put it below. The problem then is the knee-jerk reaction to <0 scores often triggers up-votes, regardless of the post's content - in some instances this makes bad posts generate positive reputation for their authors. It's not the end of the world... it's just *weird*!

Comment: @shog9: Yes indeed. I'm very aware of bad posts potentially generating positive reputation for their authors... that's why I advocate to NOT down-vote below 0, then they won't get any pity votes as well.

Comment: Well, then you've just hamstrung the voting system - you're faced with having to up-vote *every other answer* (for instance) to direct users away from a potentially-harmful solution.

Comment: yes indeed, I think it's better to up-vote the others than to down-vote below 0 (IMHO)

Comment: @fretje: but that action carries with it implicit approval of *every other answer*... Which isn't necessarily what i'm going for. Picture one flat-out **wrong** answer, two accurate but unhelpfully brief and incomplete answers, and one reasonably good answer: i want to up-vote the good one, down-vote the bad one, and leave the two lack-luster answers alone.

Comment: @Shog: I understand you, and I'd also vote the way you describe, BUT If an answer really **is flat-out wrong, and has 0 votes**, I still think it's better to put down a comment than to down-vote it below 0, just to avoid the pity votes. (Other people *will* come by and up-vote the other answers, so the bad one *will* stay below, that's the nice thing about a community)

Comment: Or potentally- make the pity upvotes RETURN points from downvotes, so a +1 on a negative post = +2 rep (or 5 after the change)

Answer (score 51):

Have you considered making the penalty for downvotes of a question different that for the downvotes of an answer? I'm not sure about it (it needs more thought), but it bears consideration.

Comment: I like this.  I just posed a question here on meta for a feature-request, and it seems the question is getting down voted because they don't like the idea, and not because it's a bad question.

Comment: I agree. Downvoting an answer isn't as onerous because there are others from which to choose. Downvoting a question (with no comment) could be from bias just as often as because it's a poor question.

Comment: I'd also like to see the value of an **upvote** worth less for a question than an answer. There's no reason why they both have to be 10.

Comment: @Ether, they aren't both worth ten, upvotes on questions only earn +5.

Comment: @Miachael: Which way were you thinking of taking this? I think I agree, but have an idea that we're actually thinking oposites. I think bad questions should be discouraged even more strongly than bad answers. The -2 rep is not enough of an incentive for people to write better questions when they can get downvoted and still come out even by just accepting an answer. I am thinking about how to deal with a user who's last ten questions got -18/+6 votes. Right now that puts him ahead of the game in reputation, but that doesn't make him more of an asset to the community!

Answer (score 30):

I mentioned the inverse of this problem in a Uservoice request a while back.

Penalties for downvoting users with < 25 reputation (or some other amount) should not induce any rep penalty on the downvoter. Why? There is no incentive to downvote users who post spam/off-topic/useless questions when they won't lose any reputation for it - but the downvoter will.

Also, I completely disagree with changing the penalty from -1 to -2 ex-post-facto and then applying it to previous votes. As an example, [Rich B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5640/rich-b) would lose almost 30% of his rep *just from the extra -1 penalty on downvotes given* from that recalculation, which is not fair. This doesn't even account for the -2 to -5 jump for downvotes against him, which I'm sure there are many :)

Comment: +1 for the < 25 reputation point.

Comment: +1 But I'd up the threshold to 100 rep... 20 is too easy to get by, it wouldn't be a good differentiator

Comment: There are some people who wouldn't mind **certain users** losing a large portion of their rep.

Comment: Whether I'm one of them that's a different question.

Comment: Spam/offtopic questions shouldn't be downvoted but closed / flagged as spam.

Comment: @gs - that's what I do, but some people do both, as then it shows up on the question page as "-1 votes", likely attracting more people to come in and flag it until it is deleted since not all people have 10k privileges of seeing the flagged posts

Comment: +1 for no penalty on some user < x rep; -1 for worrying that Rich B would loose a lot of rep (that's a *good* thing); net vote 0.

Comment: Strong -1 on that idea.  "Noobs... you can <censored> with them any way you like, I don't give a damn".  The insinuation (low-rep == spammers/useless questioners) is especially... wikipedian.

Comment: @jae - no such insinuation was made. The topic is explicitly about low rep users *who post spam/off-topic/useless questions*, nowhere does it say that all new users makes those types of posts. Flagging your comment as noise

Answer (score 22):

I just had a look at my stats and the effect of this change would be really small for me. I stand to lose maybe 100 rep.

I think its interesting to look at the list of people who lose most out of this (restricting to people with less than 10k rep) people with more really should not care:

```
select top 100 UserId, UserName, (t.DownVotes * -4) + (u.DownVotes * -1)  as Loss1, t.DownVotes * -4 as Loss2, u.Reputation  from UserTotals t
join Users u on t.UserId = u.Id
where u.Reputation < 10000
order by Loss2 asc
```

Results (people most impacted from the change - -5 instead of -1 for a downvote):

#### User            Loss  Reputation

```
Rich B          -1156 7773       
Mastermind      -944  6542       
theman_on_vista -568  670        
Thomas Hansen   -552  2430       
Joan Venge      -540  4844       
mgb             -468  9772       
unknown         -452  918        
Masi            -448  4193       
Paul Nathan     -444  5653       
mP              -440  1606       
Unkwntech       -440  8838       
Malfist         -420  3332       
Bombe           -412  8322       
Click Upvote    -412  5683       
mson            -396  2773       
StingyJack      -392  4907       
GateKiller      -388  7190       
warren          -388  6602       
Kirsh           -340  3235       
Bill K          -336  9121       
Kevin           -332  2795       
David Arno      -324  5905       
ck              -320  6869       
Grauenwolf      -320  4016       
Filip Ekberg    -316  3935       
Justice         -312  7653       
Shore           -312  1500       
BCS             -308  6844       
Jon Harrop      -304  1342       
Teifion         -304  7439       
unknown         -304  4590       
samoz           -304  5816       
Joshua          -300  2509       
Gold            -300  1056       
Claudiu         -300  8830       
Johanna         -300  638        
DannySmurf      -296  6650       
TraumaPony      -296  4192       
Cody Brocious   -292  8965       
dacracot        -288  3991       
Alex Fort       -288  5676       
tim             -288  8798       
Rob Cooper      -284  9021       
Thanks          -284  4350       
David Dorward   -280  8342       
Javier          -280  9524       
gs              -280  7802       
CodeToGlory     -276  2885       
gbjbaanb        -276  8978       
Ben Hoffstein   -276  7138       
Esteban Araya   -272  4793       
DrPizza         -272  4342       
acidzombie24    -272  4359       
Jason Punyon    -272  6670       
Ali A           -268  7412       
Luca Matteis    -268  4468       
workmad3        -264  6243       
Geo             -260  5079       
SpliFF          -260  4337       
SilentGhost     -252  7726       
jrockway        -248  6781       
Blankman        -248  4546       
Joshxtothe4     -248  911        
mattlant        -248  4414       
BobbyShaftoe    -248  9724       
David W. Fenton -244  2468       
hasen j         -244  6373       
Dev er dev      -244  4831       
Rob Wells       -240  9495       
Daniel A. White -240  6145       
shahkalpesh     -240  5147       
Chris Ballance  -236  7509       
Unknown         -236  8945       
MarkusQ         -236  8882       
Brad Wilson     -232  8417       
Rich Bradshaw   -232  5318       
Robert S.       -232  9875       
Diodeus         -228  6360       
KM              -228  4843       
lomaxx          -228  9666       
EBGreen         -228  6827       
strager         -228  9242       
troelskn        -228  7736       
Sir Psycho      -224  1193       
17 of 26        -224  7972       
Skizz           -224  6272       
unknown         -224  695        
Will Dean       -220  7464       
Nathan Campos   -220  746        
LFSR Consulting -220  7074       
Jian Lin        -220  4016       
R. Bemrose      -216  8240       
Mike Stone      -216  9750       
bpapa           -216  2974       
Spencer Ruport  -216  8374       
Dillie-O        -216  8139       
raj             -216  5790       
Omar Abid       -212  842        
Charles Bretana -212  7565       
James Anderson  -212  2868
```

People most affected if the change is an extra -1 for a downvote and -5 for being downvoted.

#### User            Loss  Reputation

```
Rich B             -3398 7773       
David Dorward      -996  8342       
Mastermind         -988  6542       
Unkwntech          -859  8838       
Click Upvote       -850  5683       
DJ                 -822  4910       
hop                -809  3473       
Joan Venge         -756  4844       
Rob                -703  8979       
Brian Knoblauch    -667  4004       
Bombe              -660  8322       
Rob Cooper         -652  9021       
Juan Manuel        -624  5192       
jrockway           -624  6781       
TheSoftwareJedi    -617  6218       
LFSR Consulting    -609  7074       
Robert S.          -600  9875       
Paul Nathan        -600  5653       
GateKiller         -589  7190       
hasen j            -582  6373       
gbjbaanb           -580  8978       
Cody Brocious      -577  8965       
Malfist            -575  3332       
SilentGhost        -570  7726       
theman_on_vista    -568  670        
Thomas Hansen      -561  2430       
rp                 -549  4776       
StingyJack         -537  4907       
warren             -513  6602       
Grauenwolf         -512  4016       
Suma               -508  3590       
mP                 -506  1606       
DannySmurf         -499  6650       
Outlaw Programmer  -499  3820       
starblue           -495  7913       
Masi               -490  4193       
David Arno         -483  5905       
mgb                -482  9772       
tim                -479  8798       
Will Dean          -470  7464       
Jason Punyon       -469  6670       
mson               -462  2773       
unknown            -457  918        
David W. Fenton    -456  2468       
Alex Fort          -450  5676       
bdukes             -445  8246       
Ed Swangren        -443  5628       
bzlm               -442  1515       
Samuel             -438  6273       
Stu Thompson       -436  4212       
gs                 -436  7802       
Josh Stodola       -427  3955       
Jon Harrop         -422  1342       
Kevin              -420  2795       
TraumaPony         -418  4192       
Bill K             -413  9121       
Apocalisp          -410  4848       
Jason Bunting      -405  7121       
EBGreen            -404  6827       
Filip Ekberg       -403  3935       
Kirsh              -394  3235       
Graeme Perrow      -392  6515       
Sklivvz            -392  6722       
Jimmy              -390  8532       
Kristopher Johnson -389  7058       
stepancheg         -389  550        
J-P                -389  4867       
Geo                -386  5079       
Software Monkey    -383  7697       
mausch             -381  6271       
Justice            -375  7653       
01                 -374  2571       
samoz              -371  5816       
Chris Ballance     -370  7509       
blowdart           -369  6120       
porneL             -364  5767       
superjoe30         -364  2701       
DrPizza            -363  4342       
BCS                -361  6844       
Rob Wells          -358  9495       
Greg Dean          -353  4573       
Esteban Araya      -350  4793       
lomaxx             -350  9666       
Ngu Soon Hui       -348  4187       
dacracot           -345  3991       
lothar             -345  5577       
Pesto              -344  6185       
ck                 -341  6869       
Patrick            -339  4852       
unknown            -339  4590       
JohnFx             -338  4428       
x-x                -337  3626       
recursive          -337  5151       
Dan                -335  698        
Javier             -334  9524       
strager            -334  9242       
Ben Hoffstein      -332  7138       
mattlant           -332  4414       
tloach             -328  3981       
Svante             -328  6437
```

Observations:

- "Problem users" do not seem to downvote that much, so it pointless making it more expensive to downvote. (however it seems rich b gets a lot of retribution votes)
- Many of the "bad users" will keep their editing rights
- It is incredibly rare for anyone to lose more than 400 rep.

Comment: yes, this is pretty much the same query I looked at when trying to tell what kind of impact this would have, and on which types of users. One caveat -- you should disallow community wiki posts from counting (although the relative percentages stay pretty much the same for most users, even with CW downvotes incorrectly included)

Comment: I (apparently incorrectly) assumed that CW posts had their OwnerUserId changed. I can't see any flags in the Posts table saying that something is CW... I'm probably just missing something obvious, but does anyone care to enlighten a very tired person?

Comment: I don't think that there is any flag for CW in the data dumps yet, but there have been requests for it (see the question re: what should be included in the data dump)

Comment: @Jon, I scraped IsWiki for questions, but still do not have it for answers, will wait for next months dump that hopefully contain it.

Comment: Do any of these have more than 1k rep? *( It might be useful to display their current rep in another column )*

Comment: @Brad, the vast majority of problem users have less than 1k rep, ill do a separate list for 2k and above (cause these people may have editing right unfairly)

Comment: ... Also who would be affected the most, if the penalty for casting a down-vote was increased to 2?

Comment: theman_on_vista http://stackoverflow.com/users/67864 would lose the highest percentage of his rep, but he's a troll anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474610/how-do-i-learn-programming-without-books/474655#474655

Comment: Great info!

Comment: -436?  I'll get over it.

Answer (score 19):

-5 sounds like a nice balance between the "completely equal" -10 (which is a bit of a nuclear option) and the "pretty puny" -2 current option.

I'm not sure about the cost of -1. When I say "not sure" I really mean that - it's not that I think it's wrong, but I have very little idea of what will happen. When people see that their downvotes have more influence on rep but cost the same, will they downvote more to feel the power? Will they save downvotes for genuinely incorrect/unhelpful answers? I have no idea, and I suspect no-one else does either. It may be worth implementing it and saying that the voting cost is "under consideration" or something similar. (Everyone else seems to have been coming up with the same suggestion of -2, which seems reasonable to me.)

I do have one very specific concern: Rich B may be hit *very hard* by this, as he tends to stir things up and have inappropriate "punishment" downvotes cast against him, I believe... *and* he downvotes a lot too. (I may not always agree with his idea of what's downvote-worthy, but I suspect he always thinks before downvoting and doesn't do so for purely personal reasons.) In many ways it feels wrong to bring up a specific user, and I know Rich is controversial anyway, but I for one wouldn't want him to lose edit rights due to this. I'm not suggesting any special treatment here - just raising it as a concern.

Comment: We have a limit of 30 up-votes/day.  I assume down-votes come from that same total.  Should we further limit down-votes?  5-10/day?

Comment: @pgs: I don't think so. Sometimes, for a question with really bad answers, I can blow through 5 downvotes for that single question.

Comment: Jon: There's a good chance if the weight was increased, Rich would spend even more rep downvoting people :)

Comment: @Jon: I can see the number of down-votes available increasing as your rep increases.

Comment: The number of downvotes doesn't need to increase with rep; there is already the advantage of greater rep so the -5 has less impact.

Comment: Looking at Sam's impact query, Rich B is not in the list of most affected users anyways.

Comment: @David: That impact query gives proportions, not raw numbers - I'd expect "older" and more prolific users to have a greater absolute reputation loss. The main question is what it would do to him in terms of edit rights...

Comment: If higher rep people would have greater downvote cost... I think they should have greater upvote bounty to give to people as well... if not, then the added power doesn't make sense

Comment: @Jon, make sure you have a look at my revised post, its quite enlightening, fyi, rich will still have edit rights. But "problem users" only stand to lose 300 rep or so which really makes little difference.

Comment: I think there'd be more of a psychological effect though, even if it doesn't actually hit people too hard on their existing rep...

Answer (score 18):

This is one of the most upvoted requests, but it's still only **status-planned** (it's been that way for close to half a year now). Why not implement the change on Meta first? Seeing how it goes down here would give you a way to gauge the potential reaction of users on the other sites. The community is smaller, but it's the most active and vocal part of it.

After that you can then work out how the whole thing works in real-time. And there's nothing better than data you can really crunch. It's science!

Maybe with that, include an annual rep recalc, maybe twice a year even, to keep the numbers closer to being accurate. You can dress it up as an end of year present/stocktake sale.

Comment: Bring it on! If the people hold onto their Meta rep preciously, they really need to take a step back. Bring it on Meta already.

Comment: I think recalcs should be more frequent, like maybe once a month, so they don't shock as much.

Comment: The fact that we have no idea when a recalc is performed is extremely bad. Every now and then you have people popping over to meta to complain about the fact they've lost x points. If you do it at regular intervals, this thing simply goes away.

Comment: I'm upvoting this simply because I like the idea of beta-ing scoring system changes on meta, even though I'm pretty sure that since I'm apparently much more controversial here than I am on StackOverflow itself, my reputation will be instantly wrecked (low as it is anyway).

Answer (score 13):

So here's the problem with changing the reputation.

You want people to post on the site, even if they are not totally right.  It should be ok to make mistakes and have other people correct you etc.  If you get down voted a couple of points for making a mistake, that should be ok.  It's a learning process.  Should people be punished for making a mistake, maybe a little as a way of saying, "Hey, you made a mistake, please try and fix this."  By making it higher, really what you are starting to tell the community is, "Don't be stupid, don't make mistakes about what you are posting, and don't waste our time."  (wow sounds a lot like usenet).  In the past, the tenet of the site was always been to be able to ask any question no matter how simple.  If I remember back to the first podcasts it was always about people not having to RTFM.  People need to be able to post mistakes to learn.

The point of the "game" (site) is to get people to participate and play.  If people are mightily punished for trying, the immediate response is going to be to not use the site which will ultimately cause it's demise.  The scoring system shouldn't be targeted towards the upper posters on the site, it should be focused on keeping the average programmer interested and coming back.  The people who maybe kind of often get down votes, and try and post useful information and get some up votes too.  Right now, you need only one up vote for every five people who think you made a mistake.  Losing points does a lot more to someone's ego (that's what the points boost) than gaining points.  Most programmers aren't experts at what they program, but they try.  The reward vs. punishment factor directly affects how much they are willing to try (the greater the punishment, the less they will).  There are what 9 million programmers, but there are only 400 people with a 10k + rep.  Does there really need to be a greater gap between the top posters and people who ask a lot of questions to try and learn?

The amount of points lost by the recalculation isn't really that important in the big scope.  It's about the person who maybe logs onto the site and asks a question or posts and answer and quickly realizes that the community suggests that "non-experts need not apply" and goes away to pay 10 dollars a month to get his questions answered elsewhere, because at least he doesn't feel dumb there. To be successful, these are the people the site needs to focus on retaining.  The site is kind of like Communism, to work it has to benefit the masses.

Comment: You don't have to be an expert to ask a decent question. You might have to put more than 15 seconds into writing it, but a fair number of people do manage this. And for the ones that don't... Surely the lame answers from people who couldn't figure out what was being asked are a bigger blow than a few lost reputation points?

Comment: I have to admit that my heart sinks every time I see my rep go down by two and I click through to see what answer someone downvoted... It's like someone stepped in my flower garden or kicked my puppy.

Comment: Some people can't write well.  Some people have English as a second language.  As far as I can tell Atwood's entire dev-days talk was on that, so we should punish them for having difficulty? 
Based on your response, you think that only experts should answer questions?  People who make mistakes should be punished for trying and clearly pointing out to them they have the wrong answer, instead of nudging them in the right direction?  Having a higher down vote tells new users (and existing ones) that stupidity isn't tolerated and people who try and stretch what they know should go elsewhere.

Comment: What's going to happen is that non-experts will stop posting answers, because the reward of getting an "atta-boy" won't be worth the potential bad feeling they get when several people serially down vote them for making a mistake and their rep drops 50 points for making a mistake.  Why would people use a site that doesn't make them feel better about what they know?  There are a large number of people who don't post on sites, because they aren't confident enough to do so.  If SO is supposed to become the place where only the super smart people answer questions,  ultimately, it will fail.

Comment: You predict: *"What's going to happen is that non-experts will stop posting answers"*
...but then ask,
*"Why would people use a site that doesn't make them feel better about what they know?"*
...So, which is it? Who are you afraid of scaring off: the people who *don't* know what they're talking about, or the people who do? Or are you just trying to beat up a strawman by putting words like "experts" in my mouth... **I'm** not an Expert, I'm certainly not "super smart", but i do know this: **All that is required to get up-voted is the correct answer to a single question.**

Comment: @shog9 you have a 22 k rep, you've posted 453 answers, and you have the JavaScript specialist badge, that kinda puts you in the expert category.  

The site needs to be geared towards the programmers who quite frankly, don't know a lot about what they do.  Occasionally they get upvoted, sometimes they get downvoted.  You have to encourage them to come back and keep trying and that encouragement is affected by the reward vs punishment factor.  Changing the down vote count won't encourage them to post better answers, it will encourage them to stop posting at all.

Comment: The punishment button (or the downvote arrow), is a much more powerful behavioral tool than the reward button.  It has to be very heavily weighted against especially considering the facts that almost everyone can use it, and it can be applied to any question or answer someone doesn't like whether it is deserved or not.

Comment: @Kevin: I've answered a hundred or so JavaScript questions, and the ones that got up-voted are *almost universally* the ones that I put a bit of time and effort into researching. My off-the-cuff answers are *usually* eclipsed by someone else who knows more or put more effort into it... And that tells me *the system is working* - it's easy to make wild guesses, or parrot common knowledge without backing it up, but what use is that? An unhelpful answer is bad enough, but a up-voted answer can discourage the posting of additional, *potentially-helpful* answers - surely we don't want that!

Comment: And yes, I understand that down-votes can be discouraging, but they can also be a push in the right direction, and why shouldn't we motivate users to put some effort into their answers? JavaScript answers are an example of something that is usually *very* easy to test (if you're using SO, you already have a browser open - just open a new page and run the script!), and yet i frequently see code in answers that won't even parse, much less work. How does encouraging these answers help anyone? We *should* strive for quality over quantity, rather than rewarding users for merely spamming the site.

Comment: @Shog9 You are absolutely right, the site should not encourage absolutely wrong answers, but the site can't discourage people trying to post the answer they think is correct.  Not all questions are black and white, answers are may have a varying degree of correctness and although it may not be correct, it's a step in the right direction.  The obvious response is to maybe not down vote it, but that can't be controlled by the system, because it really depends on who is reading the answer.  The only way for the system to equalize this is to minimize the severity of the down vote.

Comment: The problem is that eventually if the down vote rep loss is high enough, many people will look at a question and think about posting the right answer but won't because they are "afraid" of the consequences of posting something that is incorrect.  The counter to this is that people should make sure what they post is right, but many people don't have the motivation or time to do so.  Some questions will get answered by someone, but others won't which detracts from using the site.  The less people who try and answer questions, the more questions which will go with no real answers.

Comment: @Kevin - I would postulate that if someone is *so* heavily negatively affected by down votes that their contribution to the site is clearly not of any value. Quite likely, good riddance.

Comment: Totally agree with this. Sometimes you don't know or remember 100% what the right answer is, but maybe want to still provide a pointer.  It may not be the best answer, but you're trying to help.  Then you get down-voted anonymously.  That's happened to me several times, and man is it annoying.

Comment: Well I am one of those new user. Currently at nine answers, two down, one accepted but **not** up-voted. So what should I make of it.

A bit I feel like Kevin described, why answer at all if there is only punishment and no praise to be gained?

As about the “expert” part: I have 25 years of experience in the business. I am an expert. I got my down-votes for being slightly sarcastic from time to time.

As for “learning”: I could learn to be less sarcastic in my answers - but for that there need to be more praise.

Answer (score 12):

I would only change the value of the UpVote to only +2 when the Question/Answer is below zero.

Examples:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Downvotes  |  Upvotes  | Rep (New system)  |  Rep (Today system) |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     3             2            -2                 14
     1             3            20                 28
     4             4             0                 32
```

This way the poster do not gain any rep unless there are more people thinking that the post is right than the people who think is wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the big problems on SO -- upvotes are not weighed the same as downvotes, so controversial posts that have a net < 0 score can still amass lots of reputation for the poster.

Answer (score 11):

I believe that instead of changing the weights of down-votes an alternative solution could used for the reputation.

Basically instead of using every vote on the question/answer for the reputation the "vote balance" could be used.

For example if user has 4 questions:

```
    Vote balance    up-votes    down-votes    reputation earned
Q1:      1             1            0                +10
Q2:     -1             0            1                 -2 

Q3:      1             3            2                +24 (+30 -4)
Q4:     -1             3            4                +22 (+30 -8)
```

I believe that the fact that Q1 earned +10 reputation and Q2 -2 is not an issue for anyone.
The problematic ones are Q3 and especially Q4.

So instead of counting each up-vote/down-vote for the reputation, we could consider the overall vote balance of a question. That would eliminate the problem the Q3 and Q4 created in the current setup.

The same situation would look as follows

```
    Vote balance    up-votes    down-votes    reputation earned
Q1:      1             1            0                +10
Q2:     -1             0            1                 -2 

Q3:      1             3            2                +10
Q4:     -1             3            4                 -2
```

It think that would be more fair than changing the weight of the down-votes.

See also [Earning Reputation for Poor Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35763/earning-reputation-for-poor-questions)

Comment: So you are indicating that a downvote should carry as much weight as an upvote, 10 rep or 2 rep depending on whether it's above or below 0?  A single downvote could cost me 10 rep, and a single upvote may only be worth 2 rep.  Two downvotes or two upvotes that swing the question across the line are worth 12 rep total (6 rep each)?  I can't say I'm convinced.  What is the advantage over the current or proposed systems?  I don't understand how this is more fair.

Comment: @Pollyanna - I think it is more fair because you earn the reputation based on the value of the Q/A (vote balance) as opposed on number of votes on the Q/A. It believe that this number represents the value of the Q/A to the community. I think it is logical to expect when seeing a question with reputation +1 that this earned someone 10 points, and the one with -1 earned -2 points. It is quite strange that someone can gain reputation on a question that has a score of -1 which could currently be a case (see Q4 in the example above)

Comment: @Pollyanna for example if you look at the question that I posted http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35763 It has been closed as a duplicate and has a vote balance -1, and you now what, it actually earned me 14 points of reputation: +20 for 2 up-votes and -6 for 3 down-votes, I think that's wrong and that I should have got -2. Changing the weight on the down-vote  will not eliminate the  phenomena of earning reputation on answers that have score below zero. If even you apply -5 for down-votes I would have ended with +5 points here (+20 -15).

Comment: I think your solution is spot on and handles it rather elegantly. A community of users that have heavily voted on a question/answer that has say 12 upvotes and 11 downvotes means the community is divided on that contribution so overall it should get just the +10 your solution would give, rather than +98.

Answer (score 8):

So... when is this coming?

Is there some worry this will generate unwanted behavior somehow and that's why it's being postponed?

Comment: It's coming in 6-8 weeks, haven't you heard? All joking aside, this really needs to be implemented. It would really help the community out.

Comment: @pi  I'd have even more satisfaction for downvoting

Comment: @Downvoter me too! However, your rep would really suffer.

Comment: @pi, not mine... people I downvote... (do you get notifications? you should choose a username with at least 3 characters)

Comment: @Downvoter You'd also lose an extra point for each downvote given. Some (few) users would really lose quite a bit of rep. Honestly, I don't really care much for rep, so I wouldn't mind losing a few hundred points. I can't change my name: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38257/time-left-until-i-can-change-my-display-name-keeps-randomly-changing.

Comment: @alex, that's not true, the downvoter would still get a -1

Comment: The only shameless part is, that this is still not implemented yet.

Comment: I knew you'd understand me @john

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the idea of increasing the weight of downvotes.  If that goes in, I would also like to see a way to let the downvoters be made aware that the post has been updated to reflect their input.  If on my 'Recent Activity' page I was alerted to modifications to answers that I downvoted, I would have the opportunity to go back, review and maybe even un-downvote if I thought the answerer redeemed him/herself.

Comment: +1 on the un-downvote point... people needs a second chance to be good... otherwise, wouldn't it just defeats the purpose of the incentives?

Comment: This would work well if coupled with an extension of the vote change window after an edit has been performed. If I downvoted a post, and then it was edited, I should have the opportunity to revise my vote, even if I don't get to the post until the next day.

Comment: That would indeed be a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

I think the downvote mechanism should encourage useful feedback.

So how about the voter gets -3 when they downvote *unless* they either:

1. Comment on the answer/question that they're voting down.
2. Vote on someone else's comment.

If they did either of these things the voter would only get -1 rep.

This would encourage useful feedback on downvotes. It might also discourage downvoting where the reason for the downvote is trivial.

I know that the one thing that I always want to know when I get voted down is **why?**

Comment: This would be very helpful.  There are also cases where one person's answer is simply outdated, and they get downvoted for being wrong.  This happened to me yesterday.  I received a downvote, and even though the guy left a pretty generic comment, I was able to go back and forth with him and fix my answer.  It would also be nice if more people would go back and revise their votes once an answer is corrected.

Comment: For point 1, I could just add any junk comment to avoid the penalty.  There's no way of enforcing that the voter leaves useful feedback.  For point 2, there may not be another answer yet that deserves an up vote.

Comment: @Dan: true. But that could be easily sorted by requiring that you make an comment which us up-voted. A form of meta moderation like /. got it.

Comment: @Dan Dyer - for (1) yes they could, but then they'd at least reveal themselves as idiot downvoters. TBH I don't think it's that wide spread. For (2) I mean _comments_, not _answers_ - it's so if someone else has already summed up your downvote reason you don't need to repeat their comment.

Answer (score 6):

I always thought you chose the 5:1 ratio on purpose.  Psychological studies show that we are impacted far greater by negative things than positive ones.  I've heard that marriage councilors often say the magic ratio is 5 positive things for every one negative thing.  I know I definitely feel down votes more than up votes and as such I thought the ratio was perfect.

Answer (score 5):

TBH, I'd rather prefer to see the -1 on downvotes go, maybe also only for people with more than X reputation. That could encourage a lot more people (incl. me) to actually use the feature, because at the moment I feel like I'm getting punished for trying to keep low quality answers/questions down, which is why I rarely ever downvote something. (and yes, it's just one small tiny friggin point and I have plenty, but still, it feels like a punishment against me or asking me to "pay" for something that has no value to me)

Comment: Completely agree.  At present down-voting doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: But the nice thing about having more rep is that we have more rep to spend on downvotes. -1 isn't very painful when one has thousands.

Answer (score 5):

I think it shouldn't make a difference how many down votes and how many up votes there were, but that number on the side. If I get up voted 3 times, and down voted once, there would be a **2** on the left in between the arrows that let you vote up or down. It should get considered as 2 up votes, so 20 reputation, not 3 up votes (30 rep) minus 1 downvote (2 rep lost). So I think if the number is positive, it should be *num × 10* reputation gained, if the number is positive, *num × **4*** lost (or maybe 5). The so basically a down vote in the positive area makes you lose 10 points, but you just gained those points so I think its fair.

Comment: I don't think it's right at all. Recently I had a day, when each of mine answers was downvoted w/o any explanation or justification. So just because those were good answers (that is they were upvoted first) I would lose more points! that makes no sense what so ever. On the other hand only few points would be lost as a consequence of spam or an inflammatory post.

Comment: How would few points be lost as a consequence of a spam post? If there are only down votes, it would be no different then the current system.

Comment: And if you got 1 downvote after multiple upvotes, or just one, you would still never lose any reputation points from what you originally had... I don't think you understood my suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Overall, I think this is a good idea.  -2 for a down vote in the grand scheme of things really is not a big deal and by increasing the down votes to -5, there begins to be a little bit of pain.

Just curious, of all of the down votes in the system, how many of those down votes were cast in the same thread as the down voter had a submission?  n other words, what percentage of the down votes were cast by someone who also had an egg in the basket?  I ask because I've seen a few more "tactical" down votes occurring where it was obvious that the down votes happening due to some competition for the highest position in the thread.

If I were to answer a question and then have a few other folks come in and answer similarly, they could actually inflict some harm on my reputation score while lobbying for position...

Maybe the cost for a down vote should not be refunded in this situations?  Should the down vote cost increase to 2 points?

Comment: On the other hand, downvotes are more likely cast on threads where the caster has also posted because this is likely to be a topic with which they are familiar or active.

Answer (score 4):

Disagree. I've always voted with the understanding that it hurts only a little. I've never felt bad about down-voting something I just didn't feel I liked. Increasing the penalty would discourage me from down-voting at all.

I have wanted to down-vote something twice in a row though, and found I can't. Considering I pay for each down-vote, I felt that I should be able to say: this is really bad. So, there'd be 1 down-vote = -2:-1 and 2 down-votes = -4:-2. You could limit it there, or let people keep going.

Now I tend to vote without regard to the cost to myself really, it's something I forget about until after the "this is not worth reading" feeling has passed and my vote is cast. Then I notice, oh yeah, I lose a little for down-votes. That might have to be made more obvious if you're increasing the cost, or changing the limit.

Definitely the rep-recalc is something of a "yikes" that could really leave people feeling stung. So that's one big reason not to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Some users end up down voting an answer simply because they don't like the advice given by the answerer. Adding more weight would probably make these people think twice before doing so.

Answer (score 3):

I think a downvote on a question should be -5 and downvote on an answer should stay -2.

If the goal is to prevent people gaming the downvote system by asking lots of silly questions with the hope of sympathy votes, you can just adjust the points just for question asking.

I'd also like to see downvotes on answers scale like this

```
1 -2
2 -2
3 -3
4 -3
5 -4
6 -5
```

So starting with the 6th downvote, each downvote is -5

Answer (score 3):

[Some effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes) has already been put into encouraging feedback with the down vote. Could this be an opportunity? Perhaps a system where "Anynomous" down votes count the old way, but if you want to "be on record" then your down-vote counts more.

Answer (score 2):

What about some form of dynamically adjusting system, where people that are downvoted more are cheaper to downvote, as they are more likely to be trolls, and conversely, those that downvote a lot find it increasingly expensive to downvote?

Note I don't propose an exact solution - it is far too tricky!! :)

It really is a question of finding a dynamic balance between upvote, downvote, downvote-cost.  There's an implicit upvote cost by way of limited votes per day.

It's an interesting dynamic, and one could evaluate more dynamic approaches than just assigning certain weights.

What opinion does one have of people that have a 1:1 ratio of up and down votes?  Rather than consider whether they are independently minded, free spirited, against the conservatism of the middle - maybe one might consider whether they are more likely to be acting in an antisocial manner?

Whatever carrot/stick alteration you make to the system will change the nature of the equilibrium.  **This is because there are advantages to tactically downvoting people.**

It is pleasant to design a community website like this that rewards and reinforces positive social behaviour and by neglect implicitly suppresses the antisocial.   Reddit does very well in this regard also.

On that website and this one, downvotes are sometimes more important in the role they play in suppressing unpleasantness, it generally gets pushed to the bottom of the page or disappears behind a "click to expand" tag.

The big problem with downvoting however is the perverse reward, in that it pushes your answer to the fore.

*Maybe there is an argument to say that people that have answered a question cannot downvote competing answers on that question.*

Comment: Would I be allowed to downvote and *then* post?  (e.g. if there's a wrong answer, you'd want to post a *correct* answer...)  If so, the italicised implementation seems a little pointless.

Comment: Good point, it would make voting maintenance tricky.  Also, to be fair, it would lower the quality of voters by excluding contributors (many of which are talented people) from the electing pool.

Comment: whoah. "tactically downvoting"? is there "strategic downvoting" also? :)

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the problem is that the effect of voting is +10/-2, but the number next to the question/answer is +1/-1. Say an answer gets 2 upvotes and 5 downvotes, they've gained 10 rep, but it their question/answer is at -3, so it's unlikely anyone else will vote it down unless it's trolling. Don't really know how you'd tackle that short of subtracting .2 for each downvote and then rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make upvotes and downvotes a sliding scale instead of fixed amounts?

I am a moderator over at gamedev.net and they use a similar sliding scale system for user rating. If the voter has a much higher ranking than the user he is voting for then the vote can have a large positive or negative effect. If the difference is small or about the same then the effect of the vote only small. If the difference is negative (a user with a low rating upvoting or downvoting a high ranked user) then the difference could become almost negligable.

Such a system has several side effects.

- The spread of ranking becomes smaller. You need many, many more votes to get to e.g. 25K ranking because most of the votes will come from lower ranked people.
- Well respected members gain more influence. By having a higher rating their votes carry more weight. High ranked members are in a better place to promote good behaviour or downvote undesirable behaviour (that's how they got the high rating in the first place). Their votes will cause other good people to float to the top more easily.
- New, low-ranked people cannot start a voting block (e.g. recursively up-voting each other) because they all have similar low rankings so the net effect isn't that great. You need votes from high ranked people to really gain reputation and that's harder to do.

There is a big downside though:

- Recalculating rep becomes harder. You will not only need to measure the up/downvote itself but also the time at which the vote was made and the ranking of the voter at the time of the vote.

Comment: this is a complex scheme that could only exist on a forum for game developers, methinks :) also I am deeply uncomfortable with a scheme where one user's vote counts "more" than another. Even though I'm a moderator, my vote is the same as yours... (well except for spam, offensive, and close, but you know what I mean)

Comment: Point taken. But I think that the premise of high rated users carrying more weight isn't unreasonable. If someone like you or John Skeet thinks some answer is a fantastic answer then I would value that more than when just three John Doe Randoms think the same.

Comment: I thought rep measured how much the community values that individual, so giving them more wight on vote casting doesn't seem so radical.

Comment: @voyager - as I understand it, rep is only a system-generated value that is dependent on how much you use the system, not a measure of community trust. There are a number of users on SO who are building sizeable reps by contributing nothing to the community other than asking fairly trivial questions that they are too lazy to look up on Google. I wouldn't want them to have more voting power

Comment: @Joe: The problem you describe could actually be prevented by the above system. In the above system you could get many votes from trivial answers and still not get much ranking if the high ranked people didn't vote for you.

Comment: No matter how many mediocre programmer you put into a software project, they can never produce work that matches the quality of a single great developer. I think it applies here to some extent... Having this system would "silence" the crowd when one who really knows the stuff comes along. Its like when you came up with a great idea to be greeted with a bunch of naysayers. And the scale needn't be a harsh one Havn't tried it but I think putting just a 0.2 vote differences between those with the highest rep and lowest rep may just be enough to get this effect and not cause a heavy rep stir.

Comment: I like this idea, but I think that if it were implemented it should be based on the tags the user has won badges in.  Someone who only knows C# and Python can hardly speak authoritatively on Cocoa and Fortran, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this, please have a test phase, lets say a week, before finalizing.

There could be several schemas implemented, but I'd to express my idea:

Downvoted loses -2, downvoter looses -1 by default (same as now). If the downvoter feels, that's not enough, he could offer 2, 4, 6 or 8 rep of his own, and the system subtracts the half of it from the downvoted, e.g:

I downvote somebody (-1) and offer 6 additional rep (-6) for an extra. The target receives -2-3 = -5 rep.

Its a bit more complex to implement, I admit. Unfortunately, I can't prove any of its properties.

Comment: +1 for the test phase - perhaps with results?

Comment: interesting idea, but in your case the downvoter would lose more rep than the downvoted. I think this would discourage the use of this feature

Comment: True, this is why I said I can't prove anything about it. Unless, there is a way to test it too. I thought, as in real world, you could put your own reputation in line when you think the other is completely wrong.

Comment: And the equilibrium is at rep 2, you lose 3, the other loses 3

Comment: Normally this is the kind of change I think they should test out in meta first, but I don't know that voting patterns on meta are close enough to voting patterns on the main sites for it to be effective in this case.

Comment: @Somebody: your -1 was sill -2 rep for me, try it later, in the test phase :)

Answer (score 1):

**Sliding Scale Based on Voting Record**

I'd like to see some kind of sliding scale that would reduce the weight of people who are super downvoters  (Just IMHO, I give less weight to the people that seem to downvote a lot - YMMV of course!).

Some scale like

```
2-ln(1.3*dn/(up+dn))
```

gives a range with a nice long tail, but the exact parameters can be tuned as desired.

```
95% 5
75% 3
50% 2
 5% 2
```

Comment: This might steer people away from downvoting, which I don't think is a good idea. New people would then avoid downvoting which is what (with upvoting) makes the system works.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of increasing the effect of down votes to -5. (Also I'm for increasing the cost to -2).

As an alternative suggestion; How about the rep received for an answer (or question) is calculated from final score rather than from each down and up vote. (I'm not sure about this, just an idea I'm throwing out there)

Let me explain by example:

An answer that gets 4 up votes and 1 down vote current will get +40 & -2 rep, so +38 rep overall. If instead you calculate from the finishing score which in this case is +4-1=3 so the rep given overall is +30.

The reverse situation: An answer that gets 6 down votes and 2 up votes (for sympathy maybe). currently will get -12 + 20 so +8 overall. This seems rather wrong, the answer is clearly bad, so why are they getting positive rep. If we calculate from final score, that's -6+2 = -4 final score. Which gives rep of -8.

This way, down votes to an already up voted question have the effect of removing a full 10 rep. However up votes to an already down voted question only have the effect of returning 2 rep.

What do people think?

Comment: No, I disagree - why should each downvote on something where the balance of people think it's incorrect be worth -2, but the downvote on something where only *one* person thinks it's correct and 10 people think it's correct be worth -10? That's effectively what you'd be doing - giving *more* power to downvotes on a correct answer, and *less* power to downvotes on an incorrect answer.

Comment: Like I say, not sure about it myself, just thinking out loud really. I see it more as calculating rep from the overall community opinion as opposed to giving more power to down votes on a correct answer, but I suppose that is in essence the effect that it would have. Perhaps a scheme like this would work better if the same rep was given for negative or positive final scores.

Comment: maybe I'm just too familiar with the current system, but this doesn't seem to pass the "don't make me think" test.. I hesitate to add a bunch of complexity to 'fix' things.

Comment: As a fairly recent newcomer to this whole universe of SO et al,I can say that initially I found the rep system mildly confusing.I was quite surprised that the rep given was per vote rather than from final score, & the implications that a answer with a -ve score could produce positive rep.It seems odd initally that the displayed score and the rep don't have a direct relationship.Perhaps displaying the rep instead of the score would make it clearer.The more I think about it,the more I like it the way it is.I'm for changing the values like you suggested,but don't mess with the system,it works =:)

Comment: another concern about this method is: what to consider a final score? answers still get votes after months...

Comment: Just because your answer gets some downvotes does not imply that it is wrong.  If the OP selects the post as being the answer, I don't think the up votes or down votes the post has received matter.  I personally like the +15 for accepted posts and think that to some degree it could be higher...

Comment: @Simon Wouldn't upping the downvote penalty to -5 reduce the confusion you've met?

Comment: @chakrit: An answer with 27 upvotes and 38 downvotes would still have earned 80 reputation but have a score of -11. You'd have to have a 1:1 correspondence between reputation score and votes.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do this I would increase the cost of casting the downvote to -3 (not -2, you increasing the downvote score by 5 after all) and make people explain. Some downvotes are simply vindictive and you'll be making those more effective.

Comment: As for making people explain: anyone with a reputation of less than 500 currently is encouraged to comment; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes/2373#2373

Answer (score -1):

I think that the penalty for downvotes should be less when the downvoter leaves a comment.  Maybe -2 without comment and -1 with a comment.

Comment: See ChrisF's answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased/7329#7329

Answer (score -1):

As I (just now) mentioned on [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold/37191#37191), I think **the weight of a downvote should increase non-linearly**, the way that upvotes are now - only instead of starting out high and getting lower, it should start out low and get higher!

Comment: Exponential growth? How does that make sense?

Comment: @Kyle: Because one person downvoting an answer doesn't necessarily mean it's a bad answer, but many people downvoting the same answer likely means it's bad, even if it has more upvotes than downvotes *(see eg. [the most downvoted answer on the site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405))*.  And by the way, I never said "exponential growth," I just said it should grow.

Comment: *(Also, the behavior of upvotes/downvotes has changed since I wrote this; it used to be that the first few up/down-votes were worth more than later ones, but now it's always +10/-2 for upvotes/downvotes to answers, and +5/-2 to questions)*

Comment: I said "exponential" because you're suggesting that the rate of change (i.e. the rep lost per downvote) should change with (i.e. should be a function of) the total number of downvotes, which is the definition of exponential growth. In any case, your suggestion wouldn't help in the case of questions/answers with a lot of downvotes (such as the one you posted).

Comment: Also, that answer has only 5 downvotes...did you mean to post a different one?

Comment: @Kyle: Whoops, yes, I meant to link to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/871420/238419) *(Also, off topic, but that is not [the definition of exponential growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth) eg. your statement is also true of quadratic growth)*.

Comment: What? Yes it is. "Exponential growth occurs when the growth rate of the value of a mathematical function is proportional to the function's current value." In this case the rep-loss per downvote is the "growth rate," and the function's current value is the total number of downvotes.

Comment: I guess I'm assuming that the function would be some variation on a proportion. If it were logarithmic, I suppose the function would not be exponential.

Answer (score -2):

I think if there are a lot of downvotes AND upvotes then that tends to indicate that it is a religious or other contentious issue.  Why penalize them overall for particular questions?

I think it is a serious mistake to keep the -1 for the down voter.

Leaving it with -1 only makes it MORE enticing to do "strategic" downvoting or retribution voting.

If you're going to ding someone for 5 hitpoints then it should probably cost you a little too.

One of the reasons why there may be so many downvotes (there are pile-ons - it would be interesting to see the statistics on downvotes) is that they are essentially "free".  Maybe the problem really is that it is too easy to cast downvotes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we'll go with -5/-2

Comment: that works better than 5/-1 I think.

Answer (score -2):

Just let users with large amounts of reputation down-vote for free.  Also you could limit the amount of free down votes for these users (maybe 10-20 per day).  This way users who have proven themselves over time will get a tiny bit closer to being moderators.

Comment: As far as I know, moderators also have to pay 1 reputation point to downvote.

Answer (score -2):

What if downvoting was changed on users who consistently get downvotes? This would include posts deleted by others. This would mean users who consistently post bad content lose a lot of rep. Here are some numbers I came up with, but they will probably need some changing to become a good idea.

1. If a user has less than 20% of votes on their posts as downvotes, they won’t be affected.
2. For every 10% of downvotes on a persons post after 20%, the downvote weight is increased, not sure how to increase it though.

This will prevent users from posting controversial content for rep (which I’m fairly certain is a real problem it at least one site, e.g., *[Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour)*).

This isn’t already solved by question or answer bans because a post with a lot of upvotes and slightly fewer downvotes won’t trigger it as far as I know.

Also, the rep loss might need to say something like “extra rep was lost from this/these downvote(s) because of consistent low quality or controversial posts”.

Comment: IMHO, this is redundant. Any user who's being downvoted that consistently is probably going to run into either a question/answer ban, or a "low-quality content" suspension. There's no need to throw extra rep loss into the equation.

Comment: @F1Krazy if they get 50-60% upvotes by posting controversial stuff they won’t get a q/a bans or a suspensions AFAIK

Comment: I don't think it should require pulling out a calculator to figure out why you lost x rep rather than y rep. Why should a controversial post be more punished than one with somewhat broad agreement?

Answer (score -3):

Don't increase the penalty-points per downvote. Instead consider using one of the following:

- **increase *incrementally* the penalty-points per *consecutive* downvotes**

2 downvotes received one after the other causes the weight of the penalty-points carried by the 2nd downvote to *increment by say **+1*** (i.e. 3) and so forth. This increment gets reset to **0** whenever an upvote is received.

- **increase *incrementally* the penalty-points per downvote based on total number of downvotes**

After 9 (total, not consecutive) downvotes are received then the following downvotes would each carry an incremented weight of say **+10** (or whatever) penalty-points, which will again be incremented by **+10** on reaching ***100*** downvotes and so forth

This could also be applied to serial downvoters. The more they downvote (either consecutively or in total or a combination thereof), the heavier the penalty-points.

You may also have to keep in mind the total points each user already possesses, as it would really hurt newcomers to be hit by a tsunami of downvoters. Maybe a little red pop-up box could remind them that when they withdrew their answer/response, the weight of the negative points would be withdrawn as well. This way they can keep the answer up until they get sufficient explanation via comments as to ***why*** their answer was considered incorrect or inappropriate. Then they can defend their answer, or edit their answer to clear up any misunderstandings, or just delete it (and put in a new answer).

Comment: How does this help? Your first suggestion would still have two downvotes + 1 upvote being a net win for the person being downvoted (even as their post stands with a negative score)... Moreso if the upvote comes *between* the downvotes! And near as i can tell, the second suggestion only makes a difference for *heavily* down-voted posts (even 5 down-votes + 1 up-vote would still be a wash rep-wise).

Comment: @Shog9: If someone upvotes, it's indicative that there was indeed _some_ merit in the answer. However when people downvote, and that too consecutively it indicates a unanimous disapproval. To increase the weight of downvotes _in such instances_ would be the most appropriate and effective. As for the second suggestion, I have given as example limits: 10 and 100 to increase the penalty-point increment per downvote. Limits could just as easily be of 5, 12, 25 and 75 (or whatever) Similarly the increment of penalty-points at each stage could be set as per conscience to be more harsher or lenient.

Comment: I think this is getting a little complicated for just votes..

Comment: @facepalmd: _"If someone upvotes, it's indicative that there was indeed some merit in the answer."_ I know this is old now, but the whole point of this discussion is that your statement there is just not true.

Answer (score -5):

Rather than going through and majorly dropping all question points by half, why not just make upvotes on answers equal +15 or something?  Then no one loses any abilities they've worked for.

Comment: That's one of the reasons behind the whole redo of rep.

Comment: I thought about that, but I'd prefer not to inflate the rep "economy" more than it already is..

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I posted my concerns here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42863/new-rep-recalc-will-hurt-good-question-askers

Answer (score -6):

The proposed change might roughen the pleasant atmosphere I associate with Stack Overflow.  So here's my 3 cents against increasing the penalty:

1. It's good to know what's *wrong* is as well as what's *right*.  An increased penalty will cause more wrong answers to be removed, along with the comments explaining why it's a wrong answer.
2. Some answers are controversial. They are not wrong, or unhelpful, but they still get a lot of downvotes.  Increasing the penalty would discourage people from expressing what they really think.
3. Quality of information is ensured by a [negative feedback loop](https://serc.carleton.edu/introgeo/models/loops.html):

> Negative feedbacks tend to dampen or
> buffer changes; this tends to hold a
> system to some equilibrium state
> making it more stable.

By increasing the penalty, the constant in the feedback loop changes from 0.2 (one upvote = 5 downvotes) to 0.5 (one upvote = 2 downvotes.)  This 150% increase will remove the "feedback" nature of downvotes.  Downvotes will be a smack in the face rather than a gentle push in the right direction.

4. People will be very upset if you lower their reputation retroactively.  It's like saying "a penalty kick is now worth 7.5 instead of 3 points" and reordering the rankings at the end of the Rugby year.

Comment: On (4): Should not be a problem as long as the revised formula is applied to all players equally.  It's like a stock split or join.

Comment: On (3): StackOverflow suffers at present from a large quantity of crap - the signal:noise ratio is too low.

Comment: @Software Monkey: (4) Even if the formula is applied equally, it changes the valuation of past behavior  That's almost universally acknowledged as unfair (3) Yeah, negative feedback (especially the subtle type) was reduced greatly by the "Vote to old to be changed" change.  It will decrease even further when a downvote equates to -5 points.  Then people will downvote only people they hate, instead of people you suspect might be wrong

Answer (score -6):

Allow multiple down votes by the same user at a cost to both parties of 1 point to a maximum of 10 down votes. It should always hurt to punish even when punishing the people who deserve a lot of punishment.

Comment: Upvoting this because I like the idea of variable downvoting "strength" while maintaining the same cost ratio.

Answer (score -11):

Why not increase the downvote value according to the user's rep?

ie, Joe N00b joins and starts downvoting everywhere - it'll be carnage. However, if his downvotes don't count much (-1 if that) then it'll be fine; If Jon Skeet decides you've gone too far (or answered incorrectly) then your rep penalty from his downvote should count more. He's an obviously more responsible user who would only downvote (hopefully) for things that really needed it.

So if the downvote penalty ranged between 0 and -10, a user with 2000 rep might cost you 2 points, a user with 10,000 rep might cost you -5 points.

Comment: This has been discussed and [status-declined] before. Can't find it at the moment though...

Comment: But wouldn't it be cool?  I think that each of my downvotes should reduce the target's rep by at least 1% of my rep (but also cost me 1% of my rep) - BAM!  280 rep gone.  It would be so cool.  Too bad I never downvote...

Comment: just because its been declined before doesn't mean its not a good idea.

Comment: @Pollyanna - why do you not downvote?

Comment: @idigas - I'm not really sure anymore.  It used to be because I was in the beta and I felt bad about dinging other users on the head - generally because I didn't see anything that was so bad I felt it needed to be pushed down the stack, especially when I could have the same result simply by voting everything else up.  But now it seems like I'm not downvoting out of sheer habit - as if my first 'real' downvote would have to be on something that _truly_ deserved it.

Answer (score -17):

An eye for an eye...

If a downvote inflicts -5 <strike>hit</strike> rep points, it should cost 5 <strike>mana</strike> rep points.

Comment: Well... that would effectively kill down-voting.

Comment: @Shog9: which would not necessarily be a bad thing

Comment: @Steven: Perhaps, but in that case why not just... remove it from the system. *Entirely*. Would simplify rep calculation, post scoring, etc. Personally, I feel that, so long as it's a part of the system, it should be useful and *be used*, and therefore I oppose anything that makes that less likely: increase in cost, arbitrary restrictitions on when it can be used, etc. As soon as we start treating it like some evil bastard feature that shouldn't really be touched, there's no reason for it to exist.

Comment: @Shog9: I agree. Remove it. It is unnecessary. Let the absence of an up-vote serve as an implicit down-vote.

Comment: Well, the trouble is... sometimes posts are *really quite awful*. Not awful in a "this doesn't belong here" sort of way, just awful in a "this is completely wrong" fashion. It's nice to down-vote them, to leave a quick and effective indicator to future readers that *this isn't worth your time*. Comments don't really do the job; you don't see them 'till *after* you've read the post they're attached to. Mass-upvoting does sorta work, but only for answers, and only when there are multiple answers, and only when at least *some* of those answers are at least somewhere close to being correct.

Comment: That said, I could live with an upvote-only system. I just don't think it would work as well.

Comment: @Shog, that would suck... long live the downvote!

Comment: L0L I love how you relate that to gaming.