# Regain reputation lost by downvoting a deleted answer

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reputation, down-votes, deleted-answers

I downvoted an answer, and it was deleted.

Why don't (or shouldn't) I get the reputation back?

If I don't get it back right away, then how come the Community User owns [that many downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user/19742#19742)?

Comment: I think it is restored with rep recalcs, but can't recall for sure.

Comment: Hey, if you are talking about my answer...I'll undelete it, you can remove the downvote, and I'll re delete.  Everybody wins.

Comment: In this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166135/creating-the-gethashcode-method-in-c

Comment: P.S.  My answer wasn't that bad...I was just mistaken.

Comment: Yes,    I   am.

Comment: Well, it is back. `:P`  I kinda feel like this is cheating, but I'm ok with it.

Comment: Now we can pretend that that disaster of an answer never happened.

Comment: Glad we got to the bottom of that one!

Comment: How far will some of you go for 1 point of reputation! There is something distinctly pavlovian about it.  I have an image of dog biscuits in my mind for some reason..

Comment: @polyglot: Ah, sorry 'bout that - you probably don't remember, but when you were a kid i'd give you a biscuit every time someone mentioned "rep".

Comment: I want a round number of reputation (looks better)

Comment: @SLaks: Just downvote another random answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will when your reputation is recalculated. But note, almost everyone loses rep overall when their rep is recalced because you also lose reputation gained from answers to now deleted questions.

Comment: When does that happen?

Comment: @SLaks: have a look here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/how-often-is-reputation-recalculated

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that rep was lost for deleted questions.

Comment: I have no idea *why* rep is lost for deleted questions. *Surely* they're just archived in the DB really...

Comment: Any idea if the Community User claims the cast votes right away when a post is deleted? (See also [Why has the Community user downvoted over 21000 times?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user/19742#19742))

Answer (score 3):

You will now get the reputation back within 5 minutes of the deletion.  In this case we update the rep of those affected as part of a background job, this is part of [the recent reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes).