# Show changes from last rep recalc on the profile

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page

When you do a rep recalc, that should update effected users' profiles to show rep before, rep after, and the time of the recalc on the profile page.

Comment: Why            ?

Comment: That would be a great feature.

Comment: I wish everyone would stop obsessing about recalcs. They're just an implementation detail. Whenever you look at your rep count, just think "plus or minus some," and let it go.

Comment: My thinking is I would be happier if I knew how it worked...  Since I'm still new to this thing, I feel confused when it changes, especially is the "plus or minus" is several hundred.  Obviously, I love getting answers to questions and helping others, but the rep gives me a bit extra to have some more fun...  After all, we are competitive creatures.

Comment: @balpha: believe me, I won't lose sleep tonight over my meta rep but it took me by surprise to see it at 1243. Who knows, maybe I had a bounty somewhere that reduced my rep by ~300...but I think I'd remember that. ***If*** we had something that was in place to let us know our account had been recalc'd, then I would not have to go wondering what I spent 200-300 rep on.

Answer (score 4):

I don't find that particularly useful. 'Rep before' doesn't exist anymore after the recalc. 'Rep after' is shown in the profile anyway.

What *might* be useful is letting people know a recalc has been made on their accounts only, probably in the Recent tab, if only to reduce the surprise.

For a general recalc I think a notice on the blog would occur so again, no need to.

Comment: By the way, how often are recalc's done?

Comment: @Chacha102: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/how-often-is-reputation-recalculated

Comment: I **would** like to know when my rep has been recalc'd. I could have swore my rep was higher (~1500) and today I looked it is 1243. A bit of a surprise but certainly not going to die over it.