# How can I request a reputation recalc?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-recalc

The [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/how-often-is-reputation-recalculated/7958#7958) to the question, "How often is reputation recalculated?", states that your reputation can be recalculated by a mod on request.  Other than posting this question, how can I request this?

Comment: Be warned: rep recalc's almost always result in _lower_ rep.

Comment: Not always, but most of the time.

Comment: @David: Let us know how it went.  8-)

Comment: If you're still around, the accepted answer is now outdated :)

Comment: @Joel - any idea why this is (out of curiosity) ?  fwiw, I just tried it out and got 10 bonus points added on...

Comment: @eternalseptember I believe this is because questions get deleted and rep gains from them are lost

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can now do your own rep recalcs, as per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc/71678#71678).

Comment: +6 rep for me! `:D`

Comment: @Nick, I'm glad to see it work that way for somebody.

Answer (score 13):

I'm going against the grain.  **Don't** e-mail the team - it'll waste their bandwidth.  Flag a post, preferably one of your posts, and request a Rep Recalc.  A mod will do it for you without the Team needing to be involved.  I'll recalc the rep and report the results when I see a flag =)

Comment: Preferably flag one of *your* posts.

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: @Kyle can you flag one of your own posts?  I want to try, but the last time I wanted to test something relating to flagging I forgot mod-flags are insta-nuke and accidently deleted someone's comment =(

Comment: @Tom: You tell me. I just flagged my own.

Comment: @Rich you can indeed.

Comment: @Tom: Don't forget to ban me.

Comment: @Tom: Just flag one of your own questions or answers.  There's no auto-anything tied to flagging those.

Comment: Wow, 4 moderators commenting on this one answer. It's a nexus of diamonds!

Comment: @gnovice: If we get one more, we will combine to form... **MEGA-MOD**!

Comment: @Wille the Gecko: *Voltron.

Comment: Why do this, when you can go to stackoverflow.com/reputation and request recalc yourself?

Answer (score 2):

This is no longer necessary, unless you're one of [58 or fewer very special people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124863/are-self-triggered-reputation-recalculations-still-needed#comment335981_124875).

I'm actually posting this answer mostly to bump the question for "too localized" votes.

Answer (score -2):

Email the team.

> team@stackoverflow.com

Be warned that this usually will not go in your favor.

Comment: Is there a reason they don't normally go in the users favor? Just wondering.

Comment: I think one of the main reasons is that recalcs are often catching deleted questions. Almost everyone that isn't a spammer gets moer +rep than -Rep on any given question, so if the question is deleted they will lose +Rep.

Comment: @Coops: Because deleted questions no longer count towards rep. So if you have a deleted question with 5 upvotes, you'll lose 50 rep unless you were already capped out that day.

Comment: As EBGreen said, it's historically been due to deleted questions/answers.  I suspect that the next mass recalc will see a lot of rep lost due to questions migrated from SO to other sites.

Comment: I wonder if we will ever see the new -5/-2 downvote change

Comment: @jjnguy: I can't wait, I will be back at 100 rep!