# How to ask for a reputation recalculation?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-recalc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I request a reputation recalc?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/how-can-i-request-a-reputation-recalc)

I have read multiple posts related to reputation points, how much reputation one should lose upon a downvote, others about loss of reputation points for no apparent reasons, then I have hit the reputation recalculation topic where one can ask for it.

**How to ask for a reputation recalculation?**

My concerns are that I have lost already a few months ago some reputation points. I got over it as per assuming there was something I didn't understand correctly, based on first impressions. But no later than yesterday, I had about `4590` reputation points. From this point forward to the time I reconnected on SO at home, I had lost about 124 reputation points for no apparent reasons! How is that so?

Finally, I would simply ask for a reputation recalculation, as some others have said before me, I am not that kind of expert which gets many upvotes per Q&A, so my reputation represents a lot of efforts I do collaborating on SO.

Thanks for your help and advices! =)

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/how-can-i-request-a-reputation-recalc

Comment: Just recalced it and there was no change. Apparently some upvotes were invalidated overnight; once that happens, there's no way for me to see exactly *why*.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the information, Micheal Myers. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag a post you've made for moderator attention, and ask for a reputation recalculation.