# Bug in the Downvote Reversal?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

Yesterday I was serial downvoted on SO - top four marked answers.  So, lost 8 rep and was sitting at #,#22.

Looks like the script caught it, because there's no downvotes for yesterday when I check the summary page.  But so far, I've only gotten back half the rep - I'm at #,#26.  I regained 4 rep.

Is this a bug?  Does the serial downvote reversal perform a recalculation?  My accounts are linked, in case does turn out to be a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the serial downvote reversal [does perform a recalculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/how-often-is-reputation-recalculated/7958#7958), so that will be where the other points went.

Answer (score 0):

I think it causes a recalc on your account, which would affect your rep in strange ways (deleted posts are now recalculated, etc).

But you can be happy that now you have your real reputation

Comment: How are deleted posts interpreted?  I know I've had two reversals lately, but the rep was accurate at the time.

Comment: @omg, if they are deleted, the rep is restored (whether it was positive or negative)

Comment: Awesome, now I can use my sockpuppet account to force rep recalcs on the users I think are sorely in need of one! Er, wait, did I post this while I was logged in?