# So many upvotes and so little reputation

Tags: support, reputation

Why do I have 224 upvotes, 6 downvotes and only 163 reputation?

Not that I am here looking for points, but it could be nice a few years from now having a good reputation that could at least serve as a good first pre-impression when I first apply to stackoverflow jobs site.

And yes! I know that no one is going to hire me base on my stackoverflow reputation so don't bother telling me that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have 224 upvotes and 6 downvotes. You yourself have upvoted others 224 times, and downvoted 6 times.

It's a common mistake when viewing your [stats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169034) page.

View your [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) to see how others have voted you. Note that the total you see there might be a little different than what you see on your user page (the former removes votes from deleted posts, and the latter doesn't, until you ask for a [recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/how-often-is-reputation-recalculated)). I see you've awarded one bounty, worth 100 of your hard-earned reputation - don't forget that.

Comment: Perfect answer! These sites should provide a small "?" in order to improve the Votes section user experience because it is misleading. Thanks! +1