# Sudden reputation drop by 200pts not shown on SO/reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

May be I've been on hallucination, but a few hours ago my rep on SO was slightly above 3000 (I even remember getting a message about being able to vote for closing/reopening questions) yet now I found it being 2800-something but I don't see the decrease on stackoverflow/reputation. How is this possible? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reputation has gone through a **recalc** process and hence it has recalculated your reputation completely. You would have lost reputation if you have deleted some questions or answers on which you had got upvotes.

Check the answer in this link - [How often is reputation recalculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/how-often-is-reputation-recalculated/7958#7958)

Comment: But you mean that reputation is not updated live when I delete a question or that a question has been deleted by a moderator? If it's the latter then wouldn't be nice to be at least informed about the issues? I think that at least a "top message" would be nice when something strange happens to your account.

Comment: @6502 - No, when you delete a question or answer, you must've noticed that your reputation does not change. Its only when the recalc happens, that it will recalculate all the reputation again. This happens periodically. You do not know when it will again happen to your account. Similarly for everybody else too.

Answer (score 0):

Changes like this [will now appear in your user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), these changes will roll out to Stack Overflow soon (we're porting a few more things to the new data structures), it's only live on meta for the moment.