# Bug when comments that contain an angle bracket are displayed in Recent Activity section

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, recent-activity

When I clicked on the envelope next to my name (on Meta), I noticed I had a comment from a user for [one of my responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased/7834#7834), it read:

> ```
> Alex B - commented on Should the weight of downvotes be increased?
> +1 for the
> ```

But when I went to the actual comment itself, it read:

> `+1 for the < 25 reputation point. – Alex B 14 mins ago`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed, and it doesn't even seem to be that the browser is interpreting the '<' as an HTML bracket, but simply that the comment ended there:

```
<td><b>commented on</b>
  <a href="/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased/7834#7834"
     class="answer-hyperlink">
  Should the weight of downvotes be increased?
  </a><br>
  <p>+1 for the </p>
</td>
```

Comment: It's probably trying to eat the tag until the closing bracket.

Comment: It's even worse when the comment contains an html tag, see < textarea> in comment title at the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/users/59461?tab=activity .. the < is not escaped so the rest of the page is eaten by a textarea.