# Can you list how points are earned please

Tags: discussion

How are points earned?  It seems that the FAQ doesn't even explain it properly.

So far I know:

- upvote my answer +10
- downvote my answer -2
- choose an answer +2
- if my answer is accepted +10
- 200 points daily max.

What else is there?

Comment: I thought the FAQ was pretty clear. Which one were you reading?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Your question or answer is upvoted (non-community wiki): +10
- Your question or answer is downvoted (non-community wiki): -2

  *(I believe it will be changing to -5 soon)*
- Cast a downvote on a question/answer that is not community wiki: -1

  *(I believe it will be changing to -2 soon)*
- Have your answer selected as the accepted answer: +15
- Select an answer as an accepted answer on your question: +2
- Win a bounty: +X (where X is the bounty amount)
- Place a Bounty: -X (Where X is the bounty amount - 50)
- Post gets flagged and deleted: -100

Comment: Place a Bounty: -X (Where X is the bounty amount - 50)

Comment: Thanks Chacha. I hate forgetting that one.

Comment: Jeff never said anything about it going up to 2 for casting a down-vote.

Comment: Flagged and deleted: -100, I believe.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the list of migrated [FAQs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq), and here's the [FAQ specific to Reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow).

Comment: I didn't intend for it to sound like RTFM, but since it's already typed out so nicely and completely elsewhere, why retype it here?

Answer (score 1):

- +10 for a non-wiki upvote
- -2 for a non-wiki downvote
- -1 for casting a non-wiki downvote
- +15 for a non-wiki accepted answer
- +n for a bounty (n being based on the bounty amount)
- -n for offering a bounty on one of your questions (n being based on the bounty amount)
- +2 for accepting an answer to your questions

The daily cap is 200 - amount lost from downvotes cast. The daily cap does not keep you from earning points for accepted answers, accepting answers or bounties, but until you've reached the cap they do count against the cap. Based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322) thread it seems that the rep lost for downvotes and possibly for casting downvotes may be changing in the near future.

Comment: Almost identical to mine (although I did manage to leave in the possibility of the downvote points changing)

Comment: You also didn't mention that the points aren't gained or lost on community wiki questions/answers.

Comment: @TheTXI yeah I tried to leave the daily cap explanation neutral to the potential change coming.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally: for the 200 rep per day cap, when you accept an answer or have one accepted you still get credit for that rep, even after hitting the cap.  But rep received from those activities prior to hitting the cap still counts towards the cap.  The cap resets at midnight GMT, and so it's 'better' to accept answers shortly before that time.