# What adjustments to reputation have recently been applied to SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

What adjustments to reputation have recently been applied to SO?

I noticed a lot of the top users' reps dropped by several thousand points overnight.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: You just caught an early glimpse of Jon Skeet's rep 5 minutes from now.

Comment: no before after screen shots, but I'm pretty sure Jon Skeets rep was over 88.7k last night and it's 84.9k this morning

Comment: Perhaps Jon Skeet magnanimously began donating his rep to the less fortunate?

Answer (score 2):

My rep was definitely *not* over 88K last night. I think I'd have noticed that.

Rep recalcs can change reputation of course, but I haven't noticed anything significant recently.

Comment: Mystery solved. Ice cream cake time.

Comment: When you have nearly 88k rep, what is significant, exactly?

Comment: 4K would have been significant enough to notice, certainly.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious guess: reputation recalcs forced the scores down (although that would be quite a drop if it was several thousand)

Answer (score 0):

This usually is due to reputation recalculations. Reputation earned from deleted questions and answers or questions moved to other places in the trilogy will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

There will be one soon, but it has not happened yet:
[Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased)