# When will downvote incur in a -5 reputation change?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Jeff said they were thinking about changing the rep loss from -2 to -5.

When will it be implemented?

Comment: Maybe it's been delayed by looking into punishing pity upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the question is whether Jeff thinks that it's still a good idea - it's possible that he's changed his mind.

I'm also wondering if we need another topic about it - why not add your question [to the original discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased)?

Comment: Fickle Jeff is fickle.

Answer (score 1):

6 to 8           weeks.

Comment: I don't think that's funny anymore...

Comment: I do think that's funny anymore.

Comment: I believe you should say **still** instead of **anymore**

Comment: Chacha102 grammars good.

Comment: Grammars Welbog welbog.

Comment: @mmyers: Tuesday forgotten pancakes aggravated fishing Darmok?

Comment: @Welbog: ...and Jalad at Tanagra.