# Should people be able to accept answers after the question has been closed?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is allowing voting and accepting answers on closed questions best practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24845/is-allowing-voting-and-accepting-answers-on-closed-questions-best-practice)

[image: screenshot]

As you can see on the [timeline of this question](https://superuser.com/posts/301705/timeline), an answer has been accepted *after* the question has been closed. This results in reputation for accepting the answer to both the questioner and answerer, for a question that isn't welcome to the community in its current form.

Should people be able to accept answers after their own questions have been closed?

Comment: Are you just irked by it or do you think it's broken?

Comment: @random: It feels broken as I have experienced before that votes don't work on closed comments; but those were comment votes if I remember right. Although an accept mark is also seen as kind of a vote by the system if I remember correctly, or is it more of a state? Anyhow, it feels like a bug to me but it can as well be seen as a discussion...

Comment: Are you thinking closed means locking from vote actions?

Comment: @random: Yes, I feel that it's weird that for example the question author be able to get additional reputation for something that's not welcome? But Grace Note has explained it quite well and it's more of a I-shouldn't-really-care situation that is probably just status-by-design... :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Much in the same vein that you can vote on questions that are closed (and any existing answers to such questions), I see no reason to restrict closed questions from having accepted answers.

Closure is not always permanent. Sometimes it leads to deletion, sometimes it leads to revisions that result in reopening, and sometimes the closure was erroneous and it simply gets reopened. In the foremost case, the "bonus" for acceptance is lost. In the latter cases, if the answer is sufficient with or without a need for revision on the question's part, it changes nothing on the merits of the answer towards the author's needs. Sometimes, even, it takes such an accurate answer that strikes the untold heart of the intended question, that leads to revisions for reopening.

As such, I find it'd come off as little more than arbitrary to hold off acceptance on a closed question. Closed is meant to prevent answers accruing, as the question appears to be non-belonging. It's deletion that truly marks this state, and as mentioned deletion will revert such reputation changes.

Answer (score 5):

They should *definitely* be able to accept. Even if the community disagrees with a question, for whatever reason, there should be a reward for the best answer.

In cases where the question is considered a duplicate, much work might have gone into the answers, which might (especially for [software-rec](/questions/tagged/software-rec) topics) even be much better and more relevant than those in other topics. If the topics aren't merged, you're out of luck.

---

We *could* talk about the rep bonus for the user accepting the answer, especially for off-topic and non-constructive questions.