# Do you get the points from answering your own question

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accepting answers, what’s it all about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-whats-it-all-about)

Do you get 15 reputation for answering your own question, and then marking it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @Rog, if he answers "yes", it will be downvoted because it's incorrect. Don't advise him that.

Comment: @Downvoter: Why so serious? He can always delete it when it doesn't work.  Part of the point of meta is such experimentation, or so I thought, and voting/rep is much more fluid here (for example, someone decided to downvote my completely correct answer, probably because of the above comment).

Comment: @Rog, perhaps it was downvoted because "It doesn't" is not a correct way to a answer a question that starts with "Do you get..."

Comment: You're right about that, I was answering in the context of my comment which rewords the question and didn't realize it.

Comment: Arlen: +1 for experimenting, which is my real point.  And don't worry about downvotes, I just counteracted 5 of them.  (And 5 more from the question's +1.)

Comment: @Rog, for now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322

Comment: And FWIW, this is already answered: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-whats-it-all-about.  My point about experimentation here on MSO is that you couldn't (or merely didn't...) find it through searching, so that would be the next step.

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, there is a legit use case for that:

- OP asks something,
- works on finding it out by himself,
- has an "AHA!" moment, learns something new,
- comes back and shares his newfound knowledge.

He's not really answering himself in this case, he's actually providing an answer for those who have the same question he had in the beginning of his quest.

Of course, earning reputation points from that has great abuse potential.

Comment: Because it can legitimately happen, it is allowed.  Because it could easily be abused, no rep is awarded.  Participate just a little and you'll get plenty of rep anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't.

It doesn't even float to the top when you accept it

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. Neither do you get the 2 points for marking an accepted answer. Also, when you accept an answer, it stays right where it is and does not appear at the top of the list. And beware of giving yourself your own bounty, you won't get the bounty or a refund.

Comment: *"... you won't get the bounty or a refund."* LOL!

Comment: A 50 rep difference between the two.

Answer (score -1):

No, <del>you only get the 2 points for marking an accepted answer on one of your questions</del><sub>(This is no longer true, not sure since when)</sub>.

The reason is simple, to avoid you <del>printing your own money</del>creating rep out of thin air.

Comment: You don't get points for accepting your own answer.

Comment: Things change...

Comment: I recommend you delete this to prevent down voting. It's your choice though. :D

Comment: @Arlen Beiler: The deletion of wrong answers is harmful for our knowledge exchange, as we learn as much from right answers as we do from wrong answers (we learn what **not** to do).

Comment: people forget this isn't only about reputation...