# GoP - The Game of Points: Critical Sneak Attacks (Grant downvotes are commented soon)

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

Lets see how a downvote without a comment explaining the reason, is like a critical sneak attack:

- We don't know who did it.
- We don't know why they did it.
- The target can't defend him/herself.
- The target can't adapt and learn from it.
- The target can't improve what he/she was doing.
- The one who attacks isn't challenged in absolutely any way.

["Valar másino ēdruta sagon lykēdan"](https://lingojam.com/EnglishtoValyrianTranslator) :P

"Forcing a comment will end in even worse results." at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/222324
why? how? ppl doing the harm will complain more? how can that be bad??? less worse than not knowing why we got downvoted, that's for sure.

**So I request this alternative message and feature:**
"If someone, that downvotes, comment in the next 2 hours, all downvotes will be kept, otherwise all downvotes will be cancelled." (this refreshes every 2h after a new downvote)
Now that is a great incentive to let someone take an honorable action!

Dup-friend of this +-10 year old question: [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)
Related to [A Better Downvoting System](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248070/a-better-downvoting-system), and possibly to also all the ones heavily down-voted and linked from it :P

---

**hot tip:**

If you readed til here, make it sure to further read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/1422630) BEFORE creating your equivalent/duplicate question about this same subject (I wont edit above to keep it as raw as I used to think :))

---

(Suggestion) **Btw, from the comments I came to this:**

I think the "taking the downvote personal" instead of being "about the question/answer itself" problem arises from the fact of the personal penalizations we receive (or we see others receiving) when we have little points on that account, like we cant do many things when we have little points.

If we could, for ex. vote something up/down but that vote be "ignored" by the system until we reach a minimum score to validate these votes we cast (so **it would keep the votes we cast and our effort on reading and understanding and voting wouldnt be discarded**), it would lower the side effect of personalizing the downvote, helping on keeping the feeling about the downvote limited to the question it-self, instead of a personal practical/usage kind of punishment.

In short, let newcomers do all basic things, but only make these actions available to everyone after we have enough points to grant what we did has enough quality to be made public. What would be a further incentive on contributing for sure :)

Obs.: I just found an answer deserving a downvote.
The user had just a few points above 100.
If I downvoted him, he would be prevented from several actions in the network.
I saw other of his answers, they were ok, had effort on it, but I couldnt upvote any of them yet.
If I had downvoted I would help the network itself what is good, but I would mess his usability of the network what is bad.
So, we that care not only for the network but also for the ppl using it (what is the network w/o ppl? nothing) are thrown in a dilemma.
If I downvote he will be forced to put more effort on his answers, what is good, but can he? does he have such time/energy/knowledge? how long his actions will be limited on the network? will he simply giveup?
So, I wont downvote his answer right now, and that is bad for the network, but I know (I feel) I am doing the overall right thing, and that is what matters to me.
Also, that subject had more than 11K visualizations, and NOBODY downvoted it! **someone should begin trying to really understand why** as apparently my argumentation is not enough.

---

(Suggestion) **about possible anonymous comments:**

I think, if comments could be made anonymously (may be only for ppl with enough score to do so), then they would be more willing to provide help about their downvotes w/o fear of retaliation.

Comment: ^ There, I "commented". Now how does the system know my comment was actually explaining my downvote, and wasn't just some random keyboard-smashing? It's too much of a hassle to bother doing, plus, one could upvote an existing comment explaining why it was DVed by another person, etc.

Comment: In your scenario does my down vote still count as "this content is not useful for future visitors" or are you more worried about the "attack" argument that is often used and repeated by those that want to get rid of down votes?

Comment: Related on MSO: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436)

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that it still is, despite popular belief, much easier to get an unaccounted upvote on a post then it is to get a downvote on a post.

Comment: I downvoted because we are not playing Game of Thrones on SE (and yes, [we hate fun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284390/why-do-we-hate-fun-at-stack-exchange)).

Comment: @Jenayah for example, that kind of comment would be punished with many negative points, the system doesnt have to be so automatic, users must behave :)

Comment: @rene the moment you comment "this content is not useful for future visitors", I can further question you: "why? how?" and even if you do not answer, someone else may do it!

Comment: @andmyself very nice link thx! when I was creating the question, this could have been suggested: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/1422630

Comment: Unfortunately the site doesn't support cross-site duplicates nor does it do network wide title matches.

Comment: With my down vote you can already ask your self "how" and "why". My comment shouldn't be instrumental to that.

Comment: @rene nah it's ok, that link accepted question is very good as it is based on practical results and the fact this is a complicated problem to be really solved in the best way possible to everyone contentment. Now, "cross-site duplicates" and "network wide title matches" would be an amazing new feature I guess.

Comment: It would be highly confusing when asking a question on Ask Different to get titles from Seasoned Advice ... not all apples are equal ...

Comment: Hai, I believe that honorable actions are the incentive, we don't need to bribe people to do them, the reward is seeing posts/rants like this go \*poof*

Comment: Also, what's wrong with a sneak attack on a bad post? Hm?

Comment: @FreezePhoenix I think what settles it to me is this "Leaving a comment accompanying a downvote can lead to negative consequences, like revenge downvoting and even off-site harassment." from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/1422630. I myself now feel I should avoid commenting if what I have to say may cause trouble to me as we dont know what madness is going on on the other side of the internet :P and fear is always a good argument right? I thought ppl just wanted to avoid being challenged,now I know there is a good reason for that. Not a dishonor when there may have bad consequences...

Comment: @FreezePhoenix I dont care it going poof it if is for a good reason, like in w/e :P

Comment: True revenge down-voting will get noticed by the system, and reversed.

Comment: *"I can further question you: "why? how?""* i mean, that's a reason to *not* leave a reason for the downvote. I don't need people pestering me to get me to remove a downvote. It's just 1, if your question is good enough, future votes will outweigh it. If it isn't, the vote was justified.

Comment: If you find a post that deserves a down vote, you shouldn't be looking at anything else. That content has a problem and you need to inform the next visitors that something is wrong with the content. If the OP cares they will notice and see if there is something to address. Someone after you will find the post again and vote accordingly. Tying the voting to a person is wrong, a misconception of how the Q/A model is supposed to work and obviously the thing that is the hardest to explain to new contributors on the network. We have work to do there.

Comment: @rene I understand all this (just cant completely accept it as I feel flaws on it). But that person will have problems on using the network, and I cant avoid thinking on that. That's why I call it a dilemma. Shall I help the network or the person? because in the end, the network is nothing without us. Also, that answer had no other downvotes and mine would be the first. What reasons did they had to not downvote even being clear it should be? Could be the same reason as mine? The answer was not wrong, just out of context, so it would work to someone else but not to the questioner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a major problem is that we assume downvotes are an *attack* rather than a *defence*. I think about half the points you made are *still* worth addressing

- We don't know who did it.

By design - some folks take downvotes personally. It should be about the post not the person

- We don't know why they did it.

Granted - assuming its not a fundamentally flawed question that would be covered in the help, or just a simple question with no research.

- The target can't defend him/herself.

Downvotes are a means of quality control - that folks care about imaginary internet points and curation helps ensure quality posts, and lets us curate things. Downvotes *are* defence not offense.

- The target can't adapt and learn from it.

While I take exception to term "target" - in many cases its pretty self explanatory. Outside gimmethecodez type questions I suppose, If someone feels its worth their time and effort to do a teaching moment, they will, and many folks do

- The target can't improve what he/she was doing.

Well, sure they miss the direct feedback if no one comments, but there's a whole Q&A site of non downvotes questions. Our poor quality question mod message suggests folks look at highly rated questions in a tag

- The one who attacks isn't challenged in absolutely any way.

There's no attack. That said, there's a *small* rep penalty for answer downvotes.

If one intends to *defend* against downvotes, one needs to prepare their ground. Do their research, show what you've tried. Provide folks with as much information as possible...

Comment: The personalization is the real problem. A simple way to understand is: the ones that receive downvotes also need questions/answers with many upvotes to solve their problems, what should be enough to accept a downvote w/o complaining and use it to learn to question/answer better. I added some other thoughts about personalization and a suggestion on a way to solve that problem too on the OP, thx! :)

Answer (score 3):

Votes are not only for the person who wrote the question or answer.  Vote counts show anyone/everyone who sees a Q or A what the community thinks of it.  A post with many downvotes means the community doesn't think it's very good.  Many upvotes means the opposite.  A few votes one way or another can be an indicator of which way the community is tending...

When you look at voting this way, you see that it's got nothing to do with the person who wrote the post - it's not in any way an attack that needs to be defended or penalized.

Comment: I think the "taking the downvote personal" instead of being "about the question/answer itself" problem arises from the fact of the personal penalizations we receive when we have little points on that account, like we cant do many things when we have little points. If we could, for ex. vote something up but that vote be ignored by the system until we reach a minimum score to validate these votes we cast, it would lower the side effect of the personalization of the downvote,keeping it limited to the question it-self in a practical/usage way,so in the way we feel the downvote affects us directly.

Answer (score -3):

I have the following reactions to your points:

- Voting is anonymous, and always will be.
- They don't need to share why, Freedom of Speech goes both ways.
- The target shouldn't need to defend themselves - the system automatically detects and corrects and reports abnormal voting behaviors.
- The target can adapt and learn, if they aren't, they definitely didn't try to make their post as good as they could, if they had, even an opponent would likely upvote.
- They should not be challenged. Doing so results in fear of downvoting, which is a fear of making the system work.

In addition, the feature you request would be a direct violation of fundamental human rights. You can't make someone talk, that is a right. You can't make someone explain why they did something, they have no obligation to do so.

Comment: Technically it wouldn't be "mak[ing] someone explain why they did something"; it would be bot letting them do something if they won't explain it.

Comment: A -> B is the same as !A -> !B...

Comment: The difference is that while freedom to not speak might be a right, freedom to perform actions on Stack Exchange is not necessarily a right.

Comment: Freedom to not perform actions on SO is a right. You don't have to explain why you downvoted. You downvote, you don't have to explain why. Stating why you do something is not allowed to be a criteria of doing it.

Comment: Therefore since explaining why you downvoted is not a possible requirement of downvoting, nobody can force you to explain.

Comment: Under the proposed change you still won't have to explain why you did something. You just won't be able to do something if you're not willing to explain it. Whether "explaining" can be a criterion for "acting" is the very question under discussion. I don't think it automatically follows from the "right to not explain".

Comment: Right to not have to explain an action -> not having to explain an action you would make -> you can't be forced to explain an action -> You can't be required to explain before making an action

Comment: That's only true if the reason why you can't be forced to explain an action is that you have the right to perform unexplained actions. But if the reason why you can't be forced to explain an action is that speech cannot be compelled then what grants you the right to perform an unexplained action?

Comment: You literally just said "if <x> is true because of <y>, then what says <x> is true?"

Comment: There are two separate groups. One is your rights relating to speech and the other is your rights relating to actions. Your rights relating to speech may include the right that you cannot be compelled to speak. Your rights relating to actions may include the right to perform unexplained actions. But the latter does not necessarily follow from the former. It is possible that you have the right to not be compelled to speak, yet do not have the right to perform unexplained actions. In such a case you can elect to invoke your right to not speak, but that might entail giving up the ability to act.

Comment: The latter does follow from the former! If you are not required to do A when you do B, then you are allowed to do B without doing A!

Comment: Forcing someone to explain an action is in of itself forcing them to speak.

Comment: It's not forcing them to speak, because they can choose the option of not speaking and not acting.

Comment: But by stating that they cannot do the action which in of itself is a form of expression...? You are requiring that they make themselves a target of retaliation.

Comment: Thus forcing them to explain makes voting no longer anonymous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1304/discussion-between-freezephoenix-and-alex).

Comment: "In addition, the feature you request would be a direct violation of fundamental human rights. You can't make someone talk, that is a right. You can't make someone explain why they did something, they have no obligation to do so." Those aren't rights at all. Courts around the world *can* and *will* force you to talk, or to explain your actions. The exceptions are things like the American Bill of Rights, which specifically provides that no one can be forced to testify *against themselves*. (But anyone given immunity to prosecution for their testimony can still be compelled to speak.)

Comment: I read also the chat content. I think, if comments could be made anonymously (may be only for ppl with enough score to do so), then, they would be more willing to provide help about their downvotes w/o fear of retaliation. I will add this to the OP.