# Username on wiki answer differs from the current username

Tags: bug, design, community-wiki

I found the [wiki answer](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1235/176217) on Meta Stack Overflow on Russian where username contains the old name (I think that it was on the posting time):

> [image: wiki]

But the current username in the profile page is not "Squidward", but "Athari" as you can see by clicking the [username link](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176051):

> [image: profile]

---

Same issue on MSE [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7325/339911). Author is marked as Sam Saffon:

> [image: sam]

But the link refers to [waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/17174)