# Will downvoting a question cost reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

This is a rather obvious question so I guess it is probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything myself. With the recent changes, will downvoting a question cost -1 rep point, as it does downvoting an answer? By consistency it seems it should, but then again this is not mentioned in the blog post.

Comment: Instead of costing reputation to down-vote questions, a more appropriate change to make, if any, is to increase the question down-vote reputation loss to -5, as suggested in [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased), even though Jeff Atwood specifically declined in his answer. Note this was just asked in [Has the penalty for having your question down voted also increased](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338162/has-the-penalty-for-having-your-question-down-voted-also-increased).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The cost of down-votes on questions has not changed. It's still zero to the voter. The penalty of a down-vote to the asker will still be -2.

All that's changed is the value of an up-vote on a question to the asker.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any idea this will change in the future? I wouldn't really want it to, but my pseudo-OCD is disturbed by the lack of answer/question symmetry

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I've not seen anything that would indicate that that change is on the horizon.