# Has the penalty for having your question down voted also increased

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, voting

The reputation gain from an up vote to a question of yours has just been increased. Has the reputation penalty for a downvote to a question of yours also been increased?

Comment: It hasn't been done for now, but may in the future. FYI, the SE post [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased) asked about doing this over 10 years ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Has the reputation penalty for a downvote to a question of yours also been increased?

No.

Note that the [Reputation Help Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) has been updated to show the new upvote value:

> question is voted up: +10

But still shows the old downvote value:

> your question is voted down: −2

Answer (score 4):

## No

> [image: Downvote rep]

<sup>(screenshot taken from here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/218388/script47?tab=reputation)</sup>