# Should downvotes carry MUCH more weight?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

> With great power comes great responsibility something.

Reputation can in some instances cause leniency and desensitizing to voting, and voting is the voice of the community. It shouldn't be "cosmetic" imho, and a single upvote (10 pts) can help recoup lost points from 5 down votes (5x2 pts). Which is why I suggest changing the weight of downvotes on content sites, at least on answers, when and if the person voting and the person who's content is being down voted are 1K+ users along the following lines (impact on rep of author associated with content being down voted):

1k+ users: 1 d/v = -10 
10k+ users: 1 d/v = -50 
50k+ users: 1 d/v = -100

I propose not increasing the cost of casting for the reasons mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42763/1160200). I have read the question, the proposed change was very soft. Live for nothing or die for something.

Do you agree with such a stronger approach and why/why not?

Comment: Imagine finally finding your footing on the network - becoming familiar with the sites enough to post a couple of good questions and earning a bit of good reputation - for it all to be potentially wiped out with one bad question. That would be a nightmare for motivation and user retention.

Comment: Un-downvoting is a thing though @Lewis. Are people here for rep farming or content creation, I wonder. Is this all about coasting while drinking some martinis on the beach in between things that matter in life and meh with the content? I think people should live up to their rep. Life is not as kind with one's footing, so why should this be different. I wish people would up the ante and be ready to deal with it.

Comment: Not at all - but the reality is, people - particularly newer users (who, by their nature of being new are proportionally more likely to draw downvotes) - _do care_ about reputation. Whether that should be the focus or not is another conversation. Downvotes should indicate to a poster that something is wrong with their answer or that something should be improved, not used as an effective punishment.

Comment: If downvotes from high-rep users should carry more weight, shouldn't upvotes from high-rep users carry more weight as well? Why should I (on the sites where I have 10k rep) have 25x the downvote power of a regular user but still have the same upvote power as them? Upvotes are just as important to curation as downvotes, and I feel like so many users fixate on downvotes that they forget that sometimes.

Comment: Some Meta Stack Exchange users "abuse" downvoting. It's supposed that agreement / disagreement should be used only in [tag:feature-request], but some people use it to downvote discussions that they don't like, not because the question doesn't show research effort; it's unclear or useless. Something similar happens in "content sites". Anyway, If you think something like this should be discussed, I suggest you post a new question on the per-meta site of your fav "content site" after researching previous discussions. Include the expected effects on the reputation system and the community health.

Comment: @Lewis Valid points, but I believe there is a difference between punishment and consequence. Furthermore, we're talking about 1k+ users, what's losing 250pts from 5 downvotes for a 10k+ user? I mean I've restarted my account 4-5 times here, I'm not a 6k user, but I believe having too much rep takes away from the hunger as people settle in the conformable numbness. When you have 10-50k, what's a downvote or 10 d/v going to mean with -20, people have too much points to spare. I don't know, I think people would react more to losing many pts than to having many -1 on some answer.

Comment: @F1Krazy People with points to spare can bounty content to reward existing answers. I believe there is a difference between u/v and d/v. I don't believe top users should be able to steer answer orders in a Q&A or boost people who think like them, but I believe the community should be able to reprimand a higher rep user for not living up to that rep. Otherwise inertia, the passage of time and mass contribution make rep. What does rep mean in this context?

Comment: If a high rep user / SME wants to "super-downvote", they can write a respectful, constructively critical comment explaining the problems with a post.

Answer (score 9):

**NO.**

To put this into perspective, -100 comes from six spam or rude/abusive flags. Bad content is not the same as spam or bigotry (for this reason, I think it would actually *discourage* people from voting).

Also, even when users have amassed thousands of reputation, they can still make mistakes. Penalizing a user 50/100 reputation points because someone misread their answer is a little too much. Besides, it is easier to get downvotes than upvotes, so causing less reputation change than an upvote makes sense.

Comment: I hear you. At the same time, one can un-downvote when a correction has been made if it's just a mistake. Careful content creation should be more important imho.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Most people don't return to posts they have downvoted, and it is not possible to mention anonymous downvoters(if such a feature existed, it would be more likely to be abused).

Comment: I mean I think this is a natural question, but the proposed changes would do more harm than good.

Comment: It's true many people often don't return to posts they've voted on. They should maybe have a message when a post they've voted on gets modified. The same could technically be said with upvoting though.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t On my main site, I have downvoted thousands of low-quality posts. Getting an update when each one of them is edited would be... impractical

Comment: However, if a post is updated suitably, it will attract upvotes which can quickly undo the effects of previous downvotes.

Comment: Why is it impractical, people browse thousands of post and receive hundreds upon hundreds of pings from social networks and the like. I believe people are just set in their ways.

Comment: As a side note, I'm not very familiar with the mechanics of the Meta Q&A but I haven't selected this answer, although it makes valid points. Just saying.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Social network pings are a different problem, and I personally find them highly irritating in bulk. The point is that getting  notifications for every trivial edit made to a post I have downvoted would be annoying, and would cover up the stuff I actually care about.  It could also be abused.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe a specific view for these with a ping with every 10-100, something.