# Do not calculate rep gained or lost for answers to your own question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

Related to the answers given in this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19690/new-reason-to-close-blatant-rep-gain)

Rather than force or request users to mark their answers as Community Wiki when they attempt to answer their own question, lets just not count those answers toward rep at all. All other respondents, votes, editing abilities and badges function as normal.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think users should be withheld rep for answering their own questions. [I asked a question a couple weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330250/determine-current-controller-in-use-for-kohana), and didn't receive a good answer. So after some study, I answered it myself. Fortunately, I received some up-votes from others who apparently found my study to be helpful. [This has happened more than one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309383/extending-the-template-controller-in-kohana). Actually, [it happens a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271630/kohana-editing-cache-doesnt-reflect-in-view).

#### Related FAQ:

- [Is it poor etiquette to answer your own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/is-it-poor-etiquette-to-answer-your-own-question)

Comment: Its definitely not a perfect solution, I'll admit. Tensions are high when it comes to vectors for potentially gaming the system and this has been identified as one of them.

Comment: @Rob: I don't see this as 'gaming the system' at all - ultimately, the system is about getting answers to questions. If it turns out that I have the best answer for the question and other people agree, I deserve full credit for that.

Comment: @Andy - 9 times out of 10, I think its perfectly legitimate behavior. What I want to avoid is having something even more heavy handed implemented as more complaints pile up based on a few users.

Comment: @Rob I don't understand the concern here. The goal is to get good answers. If the author answers his own question before anybody, what is wrong? The author doesn't get rep for answering his own question. Only if others find his answer to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's a good idea, if they're contributing something useful to the site, they should get rep for it - unless they simply spam 100 questions+answers in which case they'd likely be downvoted into oblivion anyway.

It's about creating a repository of knowledge, if would be a shame for a really good answer to a problem somebody had wasn't posted because the person who found the answer was the origional poster - being able to get rep is a good way to invite people to do so.

Perhaps a feature where if people answer too many of their own questions that account alone gets the penalty where they no longer gain rep would be appropriate if it turned out to be a spam issue, but beyond that i don't think there's a ton of merit to the idea.

Answer (score 2):

SO actually encourages you to answer your own question.  If your answer is the best, you can accept it and not get any points -- i.e., you can't award yourself points. But, if others find your answer useful, why should you be not get reputation from it?  You can't force others to upvote your answer.