# Dumping a one liner as answer to get first answer? Gaming Enlightened badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, fastest-gun, enlightened-badge, gaming-the-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the Enlightened badge encourage the Fastest Gun in the West problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20978/does-the-enlightened-badge-encourage-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Having a week off during easter, I've spent some more time on Stackoverflow, carefully working on my answers so they can be of good help. One annoying thing I've noticed when I'm at a "fresh questions" (<10 min), is that someone *hastly dumps a one or two liner as an answer*. Later they add more and more. I found this distracting and unhelpful, it didn't make much sense either.

Didn't make sense until I read about the badges and saw the `Enlightened badge`. Awarded on 'first answer' with a score of X. Now I understand, they game it and it p... me off. Well, not really, it's not that important too me, they actually have to make a good answer to get 10 votes. But in any case I rules should probably be modified somehow. Don't know how, though.

Comment: Enlightened also requires the answer to be accepted. If the one-liner doesn't get accepted, no Enlightened.

Comment: Please read through the questions tagged [FGITW](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fgitw) here. It's a known aspect of the system, lovingly referred to as "The Fastest Gun In The West" and has generated much discussion, starting with the original discussion: [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Comment: yep, a dupe, wonder how I missed it, I searched and read many Qs, mainly with Enlightened as keyword... FGITW is the first time I've heard. A very interesting read!

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes the one liner helps the original asker move forward instantly. A correct, brief answer within 1 minute is worth a lot more than a detailed answer in 60 minutes. But for future visitors who find this topic through a google search, a longer, well-explained answer is helpful.

So, it seems to me like it's working exactly as intended.

Comment: -1 for not answering with a 1-liner and iteratively improving.