# Should up and down votes cancel each other?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I've recently posted a [very silly answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566899/1566966#1566966).  It got voted down, rightfully so. Then, I guess, somebody took a pity on me and upvoted a question.  I was really surprized that I've got a full +10 on my reputation back.  Shouldn't you get a `net` value of up and down votes?  E.g. in my case, should I have only got a +2 back?

Comment: Just for your info, you getting flagged on that post, and if it reach 6 flags, you are going to lose -100

Comment: @S.Mark: Thanks for the fair warning. It's already being deleted by a moderator.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

+10 on your question.  The current system rewards *controversial* posts more than *good* posts -- if I can say something that is inflammatory enough that it gets both downvotes and upvotes, I can rake in the rep. One might even say this is a good recipe for gaming the system.

Now, **should it go both ways?** If we made the reputation gained/lost from a post based on the post's **net score** (barring the daily rep cap interfering) even for an overall positive post? e.g. so a post that gets votes of (+1, +1, -1, +1) would receive (10 + 10 - 10 + 10) score, so that the -2 deduction only kicks in if the post's net score dips below zero?

Comment: I think you are on to something.
When I voted against and my wife for a ballot question in general election last year our votes canceled each other.  Her's did not rake +0.8 vote for the measure.

Comment: @Alex - I read that at first as "I voted against my wife" and I thought *Man, that's cruel...*

Comment: @Jared.  The measure did pass. It shows how I should have voted. :)

Comment: In other words (second paragraph): the weight of a downvote would be -10 and not -2 if the (net) number of votes is greater than zero.

Answer (score 15):

Yeah, that bugs me too. IMHO, up-votes to posts with a negative score should merely counteract a single down-vote in terms of rep awarded to the user, not give them a bonus. In the past, I've actually gained more reputation from some trollish answers than from equivalently-ranked serious answers... I'm now more careful to CW such responses.

#### See: [Should we reduce rep bonus for upvotes on posts with a negative score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/should-we-reduce-rep-bonus-for-upvotes-on-posts-with-a-negative-score)

Answer (score 9):

This becomes a very effective reputation denial tool -- if you want to stop other users from getting reputation, downvote their posts to -1 as soon as you see them (that is, when they start out at 0 votes). They'll now need at least 2 votes, minimum, to even begin gaining any reputation.

Right now I don't upvote a -1 because:

(Generally speaking, of course ... assume, for the sake of argument, the post in question is in fact objectively bad and not unfairly downvoted, or misunderstood.)

1. I don't want a bad answer to have a better sort order.
2. I don't want to give "free" reputation to the type of user that produces bad answers.

Once it is known that upvoting a -1 post doesn't give the post owner any reputation boost (and thus does not devalue your own reputation and ranking, or perversely incent bad posters), the **incentive to cast these "pity upvotes" *increases*** -- because #2 no longer exists as a disincentive!

Hmm. One thing I hadn't considered until I wrote this, w/r/t item number 1: sort order effects are less of an issue for questions than answers, because *answer* sort order is aggressively affected by votes -- whereas *question* sort order is a much looser and more indirect relationship.

So it's **karmically easier to justify pity upvotes on questions than answers**, because item #1, sort order, is not so heavily affected. Good thing [question upvotes are only worth +5 now](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/), eh?

Comment: Agree, that frustrating, since I saw some people who downvote everyone else (for a single char typo or kind of) before his answer, and never revoke downvotes.

Comment: Upvoting a -1 post *does* give a reputation boost -- it undoes the -2 penalty that was received before. There is still the same -1 penalty to the caster, so I don't see how such a change would encourage more downvoting. Moreover, there is the new rule putting a cap on downvotes (in relation to total upvotes given), so there is even more of a disincentive towards vindictive downvoting now.

Answer (score 4):

In the real world you would think so. In Stack Overflow, we like to reward a lot more than we punish apparently (I guess to prevent people from getting feelings hurt too easily and to prevent people from gaming the system).

**BUT** there has been [talk in the past of increasing the downvote damage to -5 instead of -2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased), although it is likely to also come with an [increase in penalty to cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased/7325#7325).

Comment: Duke Nukem Forever will probably ship before the vote weight change.

Comment: Increasing the cost to down-vote was pretty much agreed upon by the community. The final arbiter Jeff Atwood, doesn't seem to agree on that point though.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/Should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: How can you really say that when the tag says "status-planned" ?

Comment: He doesn't agree that the penalty to the person down-voting, otherwise the question wouldn't say that the plan is to keep that part the same.

Comment: @Brad: Good. I honestly don't know what the appeal is for that part of the suggestion - it's not like down-voting is *too common*...

Comment: I agree with it, I just dread the legions of complaints when it's implemented. Also, we've been really swamped with careers, which is on a tight time frame.

Comment: Duke Nukem shipped.

Answer (score 2):

The community should encourage people to ask. It is fair that upvotes have bigger impact on reputation than downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree. I think calculating reputation on *net votes* solves the problem of "sympathy upvotes" much better than simply increasing the weight of downvotes. Negative net votes can still have a different weight, ie. the formula would be

```
(upvotes - downvotes) * (upvotes - downvotes > 0 ? 10 : 2)
```