# The "minus -> plus" effect on reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should up and down votes cancel each other?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26220/should-up-and-down-votes-cancel-each-other)
>   [Should we reduce rep bonus for upvotes on posts with a negative score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/should-we-reduce-rep-bonus-for-upvotes-on-posts-with-a-negative-score)

What I'm describing here could have been discussed before. If so, I apologize in advance - this is a complex issue to search for (I tried!).

Many times I've noticed the following effect:

1. Someone provides an answer
2. Someone else downvotes it for one reason or another, maybe unjustified
3. People seeing the -1 feel bad for the answerer since the answer is reasonable and vote +1 to balance

The effect of this: the user gained +8 reputation. The problem I see with this is that the answer would probably gain no upvote had it not had the -1 on it. The same works for questions, by the way.

Isn't it more reasonable to cancel downvotes with upvotes, at least in the vicinity of zero - so that an answer with +1 and -1 wouldn't have a relatively large net positive reputation?

Does this make sense?

---

Update: OK, thanks guys. I'll look there...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26220/should-up-and-down-votes-cancel-each-other

Comment: you're describing a phenomenon called "sympathy upvoting": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38595/sympathy-upvote-problem-on-questions-closed .. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/should-we-reduce-rep-bonus-for-upvotes-on-posts-with-a-negative-score .. ad nauseum

Comment: Or pity upvoting -- "Towards Preventing “Pity Up Votes”…" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42689/towards-preventing-pity-up-votes

Comment: Your update was more comment material.

Comment: @random: Your comment was more start-a-flame-war-on-appropriate-question-editing material.

Comment: Oh, you mean this gem of edit wars? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44074/discussion-on-specific-case-of-question-editing-so-2518603 @gno

Comment: IMHO this is the last major problem with the reputation system that remains. [status-declined] or [status-deferred] forever, I predict.