# Weird Reputation Changes

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should up and down votes cancel each other?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26220/should-up-and-down-votes-cancel-each-other)

I joined about 30 min ago, asked a question, that got "-1", and in my reputation changes it has none, but for some reason, I now have 8 reputation! I am happy about that and glad to have reputation, but I'm wondering why i have it...

Comment: [Your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268272/python-simplifying)'s vote counts show `+2 - 1` + accepted answer. This results in a total of +7 reputation, on top of your base reputation of 1. At [1000 reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user#footer-sites), you can view vote counts. You can also show vote counts using the [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](http://stackapps.com/q/3082/9699?view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) userscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question was first downvoted two times (-4, but reputation can't fall below 1), then upvoted (+5), and you accepted an answer (+2).