# Is it reasonable to upvote in order to counter what I think is an unjustified downvote?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

Sometimes I see a question that has been downvoted and I don't agree with the downvote at all (for example if a comment that explains the downvote shows a misunderstanding of the question, or if I think it's an interesting question that I'd like to hear the answer to), but I don't think the question deserves an upvote either. Sometimes I upvote it just to get it back to zero score.

Is this the wrong behavior? I wonder if I'm doing harm by "hiding" the fact that someone has downvoted a question.

Comment: Related: [Is there an actual "pity" or "sympathy" upvote problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93356/is-there-an-actual-pity-or-sympathy-upvote-problem)

Comment: @Rick Sladkey Super interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So long as you are not upvoting *solely* to get the question from -1 to 0, but **because you honestly believe the question on your screen is complete, well researched, and well written**, then that's fine.

Comment: Nice, added to the newly-minted faq http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/130054/revisions

Comment: -1: The question asserted "but I don't think the question deserves an up vote, either", and that the vote was indeed solely "to get it back into the neutral", so this answer (by only covering the polar opposite scenario) is misleading.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit +1'd because I think this answer is undeserving of your downvote.

Comment: @Radiodef: Are you aware that, on meta, downvotes merely mean disagreement? It's hard to "not deserve" a downvote on meta.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit (You do realize, this question is about not vote countering.)

Comment: @Radiodef: (Yet you're doing it anyway)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit (Right, and Jeff said basically not to do it. Clearly, it can't be real.)

Comment: @Radiodef: I really have no idea what your point is at this juncture.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, it's interesting, originally it was a joke, though now it appears it's more like an illustration of why commenting about a vote is always a terrible idea. Why would anybody seriously comment that here? It's put in such a ridiculous spot, it's obviously not real.

Comment: @Radiodef: I was only checking. No need to bite my head off over it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hey, I'm not trying to be hostile, I'm just amused you had to check. There's predisposition to be suspicious of motives so my joke failed. I guess maybe I should know better.

Comment: @Radiodef: I suppose you think you're [the first person to make that joke](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-voting-to-balance-in-the-spirit-of-the-site#comment454000_155934)

Answer (score 10):

You could add a comment to explain why you're countering the down vote. A well-reasoned comment could rally other SO users to your point of view, and might even cause a change in future voting behavior.

Comment: That is a great idea!

Comment: Or start a flame war because this is poor voting behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Given the detail of 'Sometimes I up vote it to get it back into the neutral.' I would say the answer is

**No, you shouldn't counter-vote like that**, you should just up-vote correct answers.

Admission - I've done this too!

Comment: asking yourself, "would I down-vote this if it were at +1?" can be helpful here too... IOW, are you rating the post, or are you just pushing it towards it's "proper" score?

Comment: It's a reasonable observation; it's not good to "pity upvote". The idea of a proper score is somewhat nebulous since I am just a user who has the same biased perception of a question than the downvoter. That said, I think that there are cases where you can objectively see a downvote was not deserved or reasonable, and you should counter that. Fun fact: I totally counter-down-voted this answer.