# Is there a Stack* site that I can ask a discussion/learning question

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Is there a stack* site that I can ask a question that leans more towards a discussion? For example, say I wanted to ask: what programming language would facilitate me doing X?

---

EDIT: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/203752) doesn't exactly address this question but the answer relates and is so good it should be shared with anyone who stumbles upon this question.

---

Comment: No, there is no such site.

Comment: chat is always open for it :)

Comment: **Downvoters**: I know this has been asked before, perhaps a thousand times. But the guy (gal?) is just _asking_, and that's what we _want_ people to do, no need for the pile up. That said, volderArt you should read the [Meta FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) (if you haven't already), voting works a bit different on Meta.

Comment: @Yannis "no need for the pile up"? So, the first few people are okay to downvote, but after that, we should stop? I can see the upside to that, but on the other hand, [Is voting to balance in the spirit of the site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-voting-to-balance-in-the-spirit-of-the-site)

Comment: @PopularDemand To me this was a meh question, one that didn't deserve either an upvote or a downvote. When I posted the comment the question was at -5, and it seemed nonsensical, it's a reasonable (imho) question and the fact that it has been asked a thousand times before means we should close it as a dupe, not downvote it to oblivion. That said, if people were inspired by my comment to pity upvote, that's their problem not mine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With your question as stated, "leans more towards a discussion", the answer, almost by definition, is no.

Chat is definitely an option however.

If you can get rather specific in "doing X", you can probably try StackOverflow or Programmers.StackExchange, but be ready for closure if the real answer is "almost any".