# Should upvotes for a question balance the downvotes if there are more down- than upvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, down-votes, up-votes

On Stack Overflow there was a very ambiguous and poorly written question, which got edited by me and a few others.

Before we've edited the question, the user reputation was 1 (with -8 because of 4 downvotes).

So far everything's fine.

Now that we edited the question and made it clear and understandable there was a upvote.
So the score of the user now is 6 (+5 score).

Now my question is:

Should the user be rewarded for the work others do?

(I know you get +2 Rep when editing, but that's not the point here.)

Imho you should only get +2 Reputation as long as the question has more downvotes than upvotes, so the upvotes balance the downvotes.

P.S. I'm sorry if there is a similar question, but I couldn't find it by searching.

Comment: even if you get only +2 for upvote, OP is getting rewarded for works other do, right?

Comment: *I know you get +2 Rep when editing*. That is only for suggested edits until you reach 2K. and maximum of 1000.

Comment: In this case yes. In other cases, where the user has more than 1 Reputation it would just balance the score to the original value (before the question), so no.

@hims056: Didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: somewhat related (_not_ a duplicate): [Is voting to balance in the spirit of the site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74666/165773)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different points in your question

> *On Stackoverflow there was a very ambigious and poorly written question, which got edited by me and a few others.  Now that we edited
>   the question and made it clear and understandable there was a upvote*

So the post you mentioned has enough facts/points (but was formatted badly) which constitutes a good question, so that it become acceptable (up votable) after your edit. 
If the question has enough information so that it can be answered, he deserves an upvote even if the question is poorly formatted (Especially if he is a new user, which he is in this case). Remember, there are several (new )users asks question on stackoverflow who doesn't know how to effectively ask questions

- how to write title?
- what and what informations are needed for other people to answer your question?
- how to format code?
- troubles with language, not all people here English speaking etc

Community can help them, edit their questions, translate if needed, as long as the edited post is a answerable/acceptable question. Once they become familiar here, then they will ask in proper way. So

> *Should the user be rewarded for the work others do?*

If original question is bad, then no edit saves it from closure/downvoting. In this case the question was good, you made it better. So 5 rep for OP, since it is his/her question and 2 for you since you helped him out by editing out (well until you reach some limit).

> *you should only get +2 Reputation as long as the question has more downvotes than upvotes, so the upvotes balance the downvotes.*

You are down voting the question, not the user. And to a question, only down vote count is important, cumulative reputation value not. If a question got 5 upvote and 6 downvote, its value will be -1, and it is a bad question.

Comment: +1 Language should not be a barrier for using Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 and Accept:
You are right, didn't see from that point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of it as a reward for the user, think of it as a vote of confidence or interest in the question.

You've simply been a good community member by editing it into shape, the fact it got an up vote shows you must have done it right.

Normally the user would have suffered the full damage of the down votes (-2 each), but a user's rep cannot go below 1, so in this case they are lucky enough that the direct rep penalty was minor. Having said that, the down votes still negatively impact the question as other users will pay it less attention, and they also count towards system related features like auto banning.