# How to deal with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Yesterday I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749652/jquery-file-upload-data-empty) and flagged it as "very low quality":

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This
>   question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need
>   to be removed.

The flag was disputed and the question is still open.

In my opinion, the question was written in another language (probably Italian) and translated with some tool, but there are still some Italian words and it's unclear what the OP's asking.

Comment: That is one extremely rare case where I think that could be an appropriate use of that flag on a question.

Comment: I would have left a comment at least when you flagged it saying that the question is likely unreadable for the vast majority of the folks looking at it. Just seems fair to tell the OP, "Hey, we can't really help much because..."

Comment: @AndrewBarber Actually I disagree, I don't read italian, but for all I know, it's exceptionally well worded and clear - something that could very easily be salvaged through an edit/translation :)

Comment: I actually just ran it through a google translate and edited the qustion to show the results. You know, it's perfectly legit. Seeing as it has gotten such a bunch of downvotes (for not being in English) I upvoted and would suggest that a few others drop in an upvote to balance it out, so that folks at least open it to look for themselves.

Comment: @Fluffeh [Voting should be based on the merits & demerits of the post.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74667/210447) Requesting to balance is not a good idea.

Comment: @KingsIndian Well, this is a bit of a sepcial case. The original question was ummmm.... hard to understand. After an edit, it is well written, clear and very answerable by the looks of it. I am a bit utopian I think, just feel it would be nice to not skew potential queue trawlers away from offering an answer.

Comment: @Fluffeh *well written, clear and very answerable?!?!* are we talking about the same question?

Comment: @Dirty-flow I am not huge with JQuery, but he does say what he did, gives output/troubleshooting. Seems better than many of the other questions that flow through the PHP tag - maybe that's saying something though... :(

Comment: I think he should try jQuery.