# Why doesn't it say anything about English in the help center?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, help-center, languages, english

I saw [this French question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915951/sandbox-paypal-la-transaction-a-expire) today on Stack Overflow and I started thinking: Are non-English questions acceptable on Stack Overflow?

After a few minutes of research I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow) (from the StackOverflow FAQ), [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75091/how-should-we-handle-non-english-answers). After having read those, I am under the impression that StackOverflow prefers the English language to be used and so I decided to vote to close the French question. (Which may or may not have been a correct decision by me, I'm not sure about that).

But it does not say anything about asking non-English questions in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) - Why not? I think it should say something about that in the Help Center, since that's where (at least I) look first.

Comment: It is buried, but there is a brief reference under [Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error).  But it could be more apparent and more direct.

Comment: What happens if you start typing a question in another language?  Does a warning message popup?

Comment: Who would benefit from having a message written in English that says you have to use English?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Who would benefit? Google translate.

Comment: What a wonderful point to make. I recently [posted on this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196871/how-to-deal-with-this-question) which was about a very similar thread - the original question was in Italian, I took the step of running it through google translate, which worked suprisingly well - and I am ashamed to say that I never so much as thought to make a comment here to suggest some smarts in the system to pick out English questions. Kudos to you sir!

Comment: If people are posting questions directly in any language other than English, they're obviously not using Google Translate, and I doubt they're reading the help center.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I'm sure there are plenty of people who can read English well enough to read such a help center item but who don't feel confident enough in their English to write questions in it if they don't have to.

Comment: @Wooble You should hang about in the PHP queue for a night... Some of the things I have tried to read... The stuff of LSD nightmares I tell you!

Comment: If they "can read English well enough to read such a help center item," then they can probably write better English than Google Translate can!

Comment: @BilltheLizard If they don't speak English, at least people who **do** read and write English can direct them to a combination of 1. Google translate. 2. The Help Center where it clearly could say "Please post your question in English".

Comment: @WGroleau Actually, you would be surprised. The things I have asked it to translate worked amazingly well. English is technically my second language, though it feels like my native tongue, but what I have seen comes through in proper tense, correct timeframe/ownership and read very well. The only place it seems to fall down is in sayings, which really - if it did that...

Comment: "I may have changed glasses!" Google Translate, you're so great :D

Comment: It doesn't say anything about English on the Statue of Liberty either, and now look what happened; we have to press "2"... :oP

Comment: @Doorknob This exactly what the OP said, in french ;) For once this isn't a Google Translate artifact ;)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I have translated the question correctly. Can you remove the on hold flag?

Comment: @Laf I am not a community moderator so I can only vote to reopen, which I would have if the question wasn't already reopened. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Take a look at the foreign language proposals of Stack Overflow on Area 51.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last bullet point of [Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) is:

> - Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability.

So, technically, it is in the Help Center.

It isn't there because it is something quite self-evident from all the existing question - they are **all** in English.

Comment: All swans were also white until people discovered the Australian black swan. :) I doubt there ever will be anyone who have read **all** the questions. So unfortunately, I don't think it is that self-evident.

Comment: How did anyone other than the person's neighbor determine that it wasn't "to the best of [his/her] ability"?

Comment: About that `to the best of your ability`, people can think (If they would understand it of course, but that's a question for google translate) "Well I don't have any ability to write English at all, so I will just post my question in French".

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg To further Oded's point: the *entire interface* is in English. There is absolutely nothing that would indicate that SO is a multi-language site. I don't always tend to be the most optimistic about human capabilities, but I really don't think we need to spell it out any more prominently in the help center that this is an English site. For our SE sites *about languages* (spanish.se, chinese.se, german.se and so on), the communities tend to include a "Should I post in ___ or English?" section of their help pages. It's just not necessary here.

Comment: Although I think it could have been clearer, I'm accepting this answer. And considering the low number of non-English posts, @Laura has a point. Thanks Laura and Oded.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg No problem. If we saw a constant flood of non-English posts, I would agree with you that something should be done. The reality is that, at least for now, it's a non-issue, so why bother? :)

Comment: I am going to disagree with this answer, because it is missing a critical point - the point is that people **do** ask questions that are not in English, and then those questions **are** closed, for all the reasons Oded and @Laura say, which are 'obvious' to most people. On the other hand, there ***stilll*** needs to be a reference somewhere logical to point the question askers to and say: *"Your question is closed because it is not English, and here is the reason why `[link to help center]`"...* The alternative is an argument in comments for every non-English question

Answer (score -9):

Why the prohibition anyway?  If the question isn't in English, we ignorant Americans will ignore it.  If we aren't ignorant, we might answer.  Should people who can't write English be disallowed from learning anything?

How about

```
Spellcheck
if (number of unrecognized words) > (bytes in message / 5) then
   feed message to Google (or Bing or whatever) with autodetect
   display page which contains
         - statement of English preference in several languages
         - whatever garbage the translator came up with
         - a reverse translation (to give them a taste of how bad autotranslators are)
         - a button to post the translation followed by the original
```

The reverse translation should come from another translator--Google has gotten smarter and will feed back the original when you try to check it that way.

Comment: English is the language of computer world, pretty much the same as German was language of engineers in 18-19 century and Latin was language of science around 10 century. If someone ignores it, he will have hard time understanding programming language's keywords, documentation and so on. So by ignoring English and deciding not to learn it one pretty much proves he does not want to learn, not really.

Comment: I can't accept the premise that "using language X" <=> "decideing not to learn English"

Comment: But knowing English and not using it in English speaking environment is simply rude. I assumed no one who comes here is rude, that's all, and under this assumption not using English can be caused only by lack of skill in it.

Comment: "Why the prohibition anyway?" - because of [FAQ and/or community consensus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676)

Comment: 1. I am not American, and I think probably around 42% of this site's users is (if even that many). 2. I don't think (all) Americans are ignorant. 3. The ignorant way to say "Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability." would sound completely different.

Comment: Allowing non-English questions and answers would be a maintenance nightmare. Community and moderator policing of content would become difficult to impossible. It also goes squarely against the idea of building an archive of canonical answers for future generations - what value has a brilliant answer for an international community when it is written in Finnish? There *are* efforts to start international versions of SO - A portuguese version seems to be the first one on the drawing boards. But one mixed-language community? That isn't going to work.

Comment: Sigh, you’re probably right.  Not because it can’t work, but because of the minority actually willing to attempt another language, 90% or more want it to be English.   Could we disallow answering a non-English question until it has been translated?  And disallow answers not in English?  Except of course on sites intended to be in or about another language.  (By the way, Finnish is on my bucket list.)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: "ignorant Americans" was a sarcastic allusion to the linguistic capabilities of most of my compatriots.  As the joke goes: "What's the word for someone who speaks only one language?  American."