# What's the point of multiple (more than 2) down-votes; it hurts?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Suppose I have posted a question or answer a question, which people don't consider suitable, so, they down-voted it.

Now why does some other person (3rd person) have to down vote it? If you have another opinion put it in comments or if you liked it up-vote it.

I believe it's not collecting votes to totally remove someone from "Stack", for example like voting in a presidential election, one wins and another gets removed from post, it's certainly not that kind of voting.

"Hey Jerry, hey Peter, it's me Michael" I also not liked it, c'mon if you want to participate, put your comments. Someone already stated that this is not the right answer/question by down-voting, so unless you have a different opinion don't use the voting feature.

Am I right, or there is some other significance of down-voting, person with zero points or less than zero points, can also exit in "Stack"?

Comment: I give leverage that at least two down votes can be digested.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74666/

Comment: My point is that votes shouldn't be taken personally. Votes are about the post, not about you as a person.

Comment: An answer with -2 votes could possibly be accurate depending on the context. An answer with -10 shows such a high level of disagreement that it should in all honesty be deleted by the person who posted it.

Comment: If downvotes are capped at two, then upvotes need to also be capped at two.  Anything applied to one end of the spectrum that's not done to the other will skew the quality metric, and that's the whole point of voting, up *and* down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Someone already stated that this is not right answer/question by down-voting, so unless you have different opinion don't use voting feature

But if another *someone* agrees with the first *someone*, he'll cast the same vote. As you already was said, *why* you are being downvoted... than you know the reason. At last, votes are private and one doesn't really need to explain his votes.

More than two downvotes simply mean that more than two people have considered your post to be bad. As well as more than two upvotes - more than two users decided that your post is good. Do you also want to say that there is no point in more than two upvotes? Thats what you say, not me :)

> Am I right, or there is some other significance of down-voting, person with zero points or less than zero points, can also exit in "stack"?

Signifcance of voting is to show post quality and correctness (if answer).

It shouldn't be based on the user.

On meta sites it also could show (dis)agreement (your post isn't bad-written, just some people do see points in multiple downvotes, disagree with you and downvote).

Also, we are all positive people and rep can't drop below One Reputation Point. Never.