# Follow review categories

Tags: support, review, email-notification

I would like to get notified via mail whenever there is a new item on the [review site](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review), like it's possible with tags. Is this possible and if yes: How?

Comment: That isn't a great feature - the review queues are much too dynamic for email to be a good option.

Comment: @Oded why, I think close queue at SO gets about 2K new items a day, wouldn't it be great to get notified each time

Comment: Maybe in small sites which gets <10 review items per day or something like that.

Comment: @gnat You would need an email every day to keep reminded that this happens every day? If you're eager to review, then click on the review button and don't wait for an email, especially since the "close vote" queue is always full and there is always something to review.

Comment: no-no @Tom I definitely need an email. Not just once a day but every time a new item is added to the queue. Two thousands mails a day gotta be fun

Comment: is this a contagious feature request or so? Posted 5 hours ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353763/provide-notification-when-there-are-items-in-review-queue

Comment: @gnat It would only be fun if you view your mails once a week and then try to read _every_ mail (and review that item of course) :D.

Comment: Good idea! Let's start with sending the backlog of review items currently in the Close Vote Queue on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wanted this for gaming.stackexchange.com. In the review queues I can use ("First posts" and "Late answers") there are currently no items. In "Low quality posts" there's currently one item. It would definitely not overflow my inbox. And even if it did, that's my fault if I set it up that way! It's not a good style for a website to require the user to go onto it regularly to check if there is something. That's what notification mails are for. Settings could be like for tags: 15 minutes, (something in between that I forgot), 1 day.

Comment: Also: If you don't think this would be a great feature, can't you just write "no" as an answer and say that you wouldn't like it? That doesn't automatically mean that this is a bad question. People in the future might want the same (as the other post today proves). When they go to this page, they can see an argument to why this would be good or bad. Also: It's just an option. It might not be the best idea ever, but it wouldn't hurt the page. I think some people use downvotes too often. I see it on Arqade daily: I get a mail for a new question, it already has downvotes, even valid questions.

Comment: Upvoted not because I think this is a good feature request, but to reverse undeserved downvotes.

Comment: @JohnMiliter: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-voting-to-balance-in-the-spirit-of-the-site

Comment: Since this is not a very bad question (as proven by the three scripts made for it already), there was also something going wrong that caused it to be downvoted, so I would say that a balance upvote is ok. Also: This post has so many different votes now that I have 24 reputation points *more* than before I asked this question, but it itself has a score of -6.

Comment: @Fabian Apparently, on the META sites, a downvote doesn't indicate a bad question, it simply expresses disagreement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, let's not do that. (I have down voted your feature request for that reason, not because you asked a bad question).

First of all reviews are highly volatile (or at least they should be) on most sites. By the time you receive an email the review item or queue (still not sure what you want to follow) is probably gone/handled.

I'm active on Stack Overflow and have the Close Vote privilege which opens the close vote queue for me. I don't fancy getting notifications for available reviews in that queue (currently sitting at around 10K).

There is one other nasty thing with the current /review implementation and that is its performance. That isn't great to say the least and causes trouble, specially on Stack Overflow, now and then. To add more strain to this functionality without a proper re-engineering would only cause more problems, not less.

You can however check if a userscript might help in addressing your immediate needs. There are a couple available at the moment:

- [Review Stalker Reloaded: A cross-site dashboard for reviews](https://stackapps.com/questions/6869/review-stalker-reloaded-a-cross-site-dashboard-for-reviews)
- [Review Stalker user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4086/review-stalker-user-script)
- [Review Queue Desktop Notification Script](https://stackapps.com/questions/6517/review-queue-desktop-notification-script)

Give them a testrun to see if they fit in your workflow.

Comment: The first and third seem to run great (only tested for a few minutes yet). Thank you! I hope the question doesn't get closed automatically because of the downvotes, then your answer will be lost.

Comment: @Fabian as long as this answer is upvoted and/or accepted the question cannot be deleted nor [roomba-ed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/158100), so no worries about that.

Comment: Btw, I'm using this for a few weeks now and it works great. The third linked script notifies me when there's a new item (which only happens every few hours btw) and when I go to the tab, it already shows me the review item. It's definitely not too much, as some comments suggested.