# Penalize upvotes to very poor quality posts

Tags: feature-request, voting, etiquette, up-votes

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498112/c-sharp-windows-application-audio-recording) triggered my thoughts, but it is surely not the "best" (or I should say, worst) example out there. At the moment of writing, this question has 4 downvotes **and 1 upvote**. It is obvious that this question is of very poor quality, as it shows no effort and basically just says, "I want to do X with Y". It does not even *ask a question*.

(To avoid misunderstanding in case the question is edited, copying below)

> I want to record voice through microphones and store on local disk.
>
> This should be done using C# in a Windows application.

There seems no good reason why anyone would upvote this question. (To obtain a badge, maybe? But that's not a *good* reason.)

Do you think in such cases, there should be a penalty for *upvoting*? This would deter people from randomly upvoting without really understanding what upvote means.

I understand there would be some issues to consider. For instance, how do you decide what is a very low quality post? Too many downvotes could be one criteria, but then being in the minority does not always mean you are wrong.

Does the system already handle this situation? If not, can something be done about this?

Comment: I agree dumb upvoting is a problem, but penalizing voting isn't going to work....

Comment: @Rory I had to pick the closest match. This is the last time I make any suggestion to improve this site, so I hope it is not too much of a problem.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai no I was just wondering how a feature request was gathering too localised vote-to-close votes, doesn't really make sense to me.  Also, just double checking that you know [votes are taken differently on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @Rory In that case I do not want to waste any more time here. What's the point of trying to improve the site if the community admonishes anyone who thinks out of their comfort zone, and basically doesn't want to listen to anything which challenges status quo? I will just stick to the main sites. Goodbye.

Comment: Admonish? Not listening? I'm sorry, I just happen to disagree with what you propose. That is the "danger" of a proposal. And if you're worried about the downvotes, those are often used to indicate simple disagreement here on Meta. You win some, you lose some. If that bothers you, yeah, perhaps don't make feature requests. But I wouldn't let that stop me if I had an honest idea.

Comment: Fine. I won't make any more feature requests.

Comment: Suit yourself. I think it's a shame though. Don't get too hung up on an idea not being well received. And you received 2 upvotes as well. Against 9 downvotes. In the greater scheme of a million(?) users that doesn't mean a whole lot.

Comment: Haven't you heard? All feature requests start at -100. (besides, upvotes on crap are inevitable...just look at some of the top 50 questions on SO)

Comment: *must... resist... temptation... to upvote*

Comment: 9 downvotes, and how many cared to explain why they don't like the idea? "I don't like your idea, but I don't know why. But I don't like it." Either agree or disagree with someone, but let it be your own opinion. Don't just follow the herd having no clue why you are doing it.

Comment: Their explanation might be given by the upvotes I received. Downvotes happen. Get over it.

Comment: No downvoter is under any obligation to leave any explanation for their downvotes whatsoever.

Answer (score 14):

Except for issues falling under vote-fraud, users are free to vote however they see fit. If they find a question to be helpful where the general community does not share this point of view, they should not be penalized for that. Voting is anonymous and the reasoning behind a vote (up or down) is entirely free to the user.

I see no reason to change this at all. Overall the community tends to settle on a reasonable total, and I don't think that the problem you address is so significant that it needs such a drastic solution.

If **you** think a question is poor, downvote it. If you think it should be improved and you can do so, improve it. If you think it should not be open and you can vote to close, by all means vote. Address the question, but don't interfere with the voting behaviour of other users.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, [I'm with Yannis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164556/159251) (whether he was serious or not): let's "penalize" -- charge rep for -- *all* upvotes. I believe that the original impetus for making downvotes cost rep was that they should be taken seriously and used with care and thought. The same reason applies equally to upvotes, so let's make them cost some rep too.

Comment: Retroactively, even. Eeek!

Comment: Only on answers then?

Comment: @Bart: I'm more interested in questions, actually, like the OP here. We could make it mirrored -- answer: upvote free, downvote -1; question: upvote -1, downvote free.

Comment: Oh sure, you just want users to safely upvote your proposal here without retroactively losing their rep in the future. :p Interesting idea though.

Comment: Blast, you've seen through me!