# Make upvotes worth only +2 while a post's score is negative

Tags: feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we reduce rep bonus for upvotes on posts with a negative score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/should-we-reduce-rep-bonus-for-upvotes-on-posts-with-a-negative-score)

This is a refinement of another proposal: [Should we reduce rep bonus for upvotes on posts with a negative score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/)

While the existence of sympathy voting may not be solvable, it's lopsided effect on reputation is.  I suggest that while a post's score is in negative territory, upvotes only provide +2 rep to cancel the downvote.

The current system is

```
reputation += (upvotes * 10) - (downvotes * 2)
```

Revised proposal is:

```
upvote() {
    rep += score >= 0 ? 10 : 2
}

downvote() {
    rep -= 2;
}
```

This way when a post is voted down early and then someone comes along and says "it's not *that* bad" the poster doesn't end up getting a nice sympathy bonus out of it.

Comment: Ironic that this currently has one up and one down, getting me +8

Comment: This has, of course, been discussed before, and I believe the issues is that any such scheme requires a query against a large table every time a vote is cast and there have concerns about performance and scaling.

Comment: Query against a large table? Like the one that shows the current detailed score every time we load the page or view the question anywhere else?

Comment: Pity upvotes are not even close to being the worst problem with reputation.

Comment: This will increase the weight of a downvote from 2 to 10 for most questions and answers (as most have a positive score).

Comment: @Paul - What you see is a denormalized number just for this reason and does *not* run a large query every load, it's already totaled up.

Comment: @Peter - that's a good point.  I've revised it to see if the idea fares any better with that trait removed

Comment: Actually, after accounting for peter's point it's become the same as the other proposal, so i'll vote to close

Comment: @Nick yeah, but the proposal was calling for special behavior only when the question was negatively scored, which is precisely when that number is helpful.

Comment: @Paul - I'm not following - I was saying that what you call a query against a large table...isn't, it's a denormalized value so there's *no* cost when viewing currently.  As @dmckee said, the proposal would be a *very* serious performance problem and introduce a slew of new deadlocks situations (which are already affecting SO to some extent, the team's doing a great job of eliminating them).

Comment: @Nick I was merely mirroring dmckee's statement that it was against a large table. I agree, getting the current value would be at no cost. I see what you're saying about deadlocks though - up vs. down votes varying in weight could introduce serious complexity. I had thought that the system really did work via a running tally though, which means that if I know what the current value on the question is, an upvote is (at this moment) just an addition of x rep to the total, which would be cheap.